# How to update Ruby to 1.9.x on Mac?

Tags: ruby, macos, installation

I have created a new user account on my mac and I am trying to update to the current version of ruby on it (1.9.2) from the snow leopard default of 1.8.7. Can somebody point me to tutorial or explain the best method to update Ruby on my mac from 1.8 to 1.9.2? Thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I'll make a strong suggestion for [rvm](http://rvm.io/).

It's a great way to manage multiple Rubies and gems sets without colliding with the system version.

---

I'll add that now (4/2/2013), I use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/) a lot, because my needs are simple. RVM is great, but it's got a lot of capability I never need, so I have it on some machines and rbenv on my desktop and laptop. It's worth checking out both and seeing which works best for your needs.

Comment: Agreed. And even if multiple versions aren't an issue (ha!) rvm is great for finding out which native libraries are missing. Pretty much indispensable.

Answer (score 198):

As *The Tin Man* suggests (above) **RVM** (*Ruby Version Manager*) is the *Standard* for upgrading your Ruby installation on OSX: https://rvm.io

To get started, open a **Terminal** Window and issue the following command:

```
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

( you will need to *trust* the RVM Dev Team that the command is *not malicious* - if you're a *paranoid penguin* like me, you can always go read the *source*: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm ) When it's complete you **need to restart the terminal** to get the `rvm` command working.

```
rvm list known
```

( shows you the *latest available versions* of Ruby )

```
rvm install ruby-2.3.1
```

For a specific version, followed by

```
rvm use ruby-2.3.1
```

**or** if you just want the latest (current) version:

```
rvm install current && rvm use current
```

( installs the current stable release - at time of writing ruby-2.3.1 - please update this wiki when new versions released )

**Note on Compiling Ruby**: In my case I also had to install **Homebrew** [Link](https://brew.sh) to get the *gems* I needed ([RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails)) which in turn forces you to install **Xcode** (if you haven't already) https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835 **AND/OR** install the GCC package from: https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer to avoid errors running "*make*".

**Edit:** As of *Mavericks* you can choose to install only the Xcode command line tools instead of the whole Xcode package, which comes with gcc and lots of other things you might need for building packages. It can be installed by running `xcode-select --install` and following the on-screen prompt.

- Examples: https://rvm.io/workflow/examples/
- Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

**Note on erros**: if you get the error "**RVM is not a function**" while trying this command,
visit: [How do I change my Ruby version using RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663936/) for the solution.

Comment: Setting all of this up on Mountain Lion takes a lot of patience.  If you run into an error "Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/..." it's not your paths, and you will see in the log that it's that openssl (which is probably installed) is busted in RVM and they provide a page on working through it https://rvm.io/packages/openssl/

Comment: I truly hate the mess that is Ruby. It's a shambles. However, this answer got me on the right path and many thanks indeed for that!

Comment: Wandering between posts which lead me to other problems, I found this one very helpful as it explains how to use RVM, not only use it.

Answer (score 19):

With brew this is a one-liner:

(assuming that you have tapped homebrew/versions, which can be done by running `brew tap homebrew/versions`)

```
brew install ruby193
```

Worked out of the box for me on OS X 10.8.4. Or if you want 2.0, you just `brew install ruby`

More generally, `brew search ruby` shows you the different repos available, and if you want to get really specific you can use `brew versions ruby` and checkout a specific version instead.

Comment: Great one-liner for installing a *specific* version of ruby! switching between ruby versions with brew is not quite as easy ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730676

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an older post, but i wanna add some extra informations about that.
Firstly, i think that `rvm` does great **BUT** it wasn't updating ruby from my system (MAC OS Yosemite).

What `rvm`was doing : installing to another location and setting up the path there to my environment variable ... And i was kinda bored, because i had two ruby now on my system.

So to fix that, i uninstalled the `rvm`, then used the Homebrew package manager available [here](http://brew.sh) and installed ruby throw terminal command by doing `brew install ruby`.

And then, everything was working perfectly !
The ruby from my system was updated !
Hope it will help for the next adventurers !

Comment: I was struggling to decide whether should I use `rvm` or `brew`. this helps. thanks

Comment: Doesn't brew also do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

I'll disagree with The Tin Man here. I regard [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) as preferable to RVM. `rbenv` doesn't interfere drastically with your shell the way RVM does, and it lets you add separate Ruby installations in ordinary folders that you can examine directly. It allows you to compile Ruby yourself. Good outline of the differences here: https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F

I provide instructions for compiling Ruby 1.9 for rbenv [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12361446/341994). Further, more detailed information [here](http://www.apeth.com/nonblog/stories/ruby193.html). I have used this technique with easy success on Snow Leopard, Lion, and Mountain Lion.

Comment: At the time this question was originally asked, rbenv wasn't an option. Times change, as does code. RVM is still a good choice, but it is heavyweight in comparison to rbenv. I use both on different machines, because they're both useful in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

Dan Benjamin's Hivelogic article [Installing Ruby, RubyGems, and Rails on Snow Leopard](http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-ruby-rubygems-and-rails-on-snow-leopard/) is the recommended place to go although the article is for 1.8, so here's a [Ruby 1.9-specific install on Snow Leopard](http://wonko.com/post/how-to-compile-ruby-191). Watch out for the 64-bit thing... either go all 64-bit 'fat' (as is - for example - Apache on OS X, which can cause problems with 32-bit libraries) or check any gems you're likely to use to make sure they're okay for 64-bit.

Answer (score 2):

This command actually works

`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, the bundler version may be too high for your version of rails.

I ran into the same problem using Rails 3.0.1 which requires Bundler v1.0.0 - v1.0.22

Check your bundler version using: `gem list bundler`

If your bundler version is not within the appropriate range, I found this solution to work: `rvm @global do gem uninstall bundler`

Note: rvm is required for this solution... another case for why you should be using rvm in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

There are several other version managers to consider, [see for a few examples](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/ruby_version_management) and one that's not listed there that I'll be giving a try soon is [ch-ruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby). I tried rbenv but had too many problems with it. RVM is my mainstay, though it sometimes has the odd problem (hence my wish to try ch-ruby when I get a chance). I wouldn't touch the system Ruby, as other things may rely on it.

I should add I've also compiled my own Ruby several times, and using the Hivelogic article (as Dave Everitt has suggested) is a good idea if you take that route.