# How can I switch to ruby 1.9.3 installed using Homebrew?

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-lion, homebrew

I have installed ruby 1.9.3 using [hombrew](https://brew.sh/)

> brew install ruby

But default 1.8.7 is still used. How can I switch osx to use 1.9.3 as default ruby?

Comment: Executing: export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" - then reloading iterm solved it for me.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at [rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).
You can then set it as default with `rvm use 1.9.3 --default`

But if you are happy with your homebrew install.

Then just change the precedence of directories in the `PATH`

Here is my /etc/paths

```
# homebrews should always take precedence
/usr/local/bin

# the default stack
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

This is important generally for homebrew, else the system version of git, ruby, pg_admin,... will all be used instead of the brew version.

if you say `which -a ruby` you'll see all the installed rubies, and the precedence in the `PATH`

eg.

```
$ which -a ruby
/Users/matthew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
/Users/matthew/.rvm/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

---

UPDATE: I now don't think you should change `/etc/paths`

Instead you need to check which of `.profile`, `.bashrc`, or `.bash_login` is being loaded in your shell, and just add `/usr/local/bin` to your path.

For me, I only have a `.profile`. You can create that file if none of those files already exist in your home directory.

```
# homebrews should always take precedence
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Finally i choose rbenv, previously used rvm too.

Comment: cool. I suggest you make the changes to your /etc/paths anyway though. I used to get weird errors (eg. I'd `brew upgrade git`, but the version didn't change. turns out I was never using the brew version)

Comment: Thank you for providing an actual answer rather than just saying "use rvm". Not everybody can use RVM and I hate when the top answer just tells OP to do something that they didn't ask how to do.

Comment: This did the trick:
http://www.interworks.com/blogs/ckaukis/2013/03/05/installing-ruby-200-rvm-and-homebrew-mac-os-x-108-mountain-lion

Comment: I had problems compiling ruby using rvm so I ended up going with rbenv instead since it worked without issues.

Comment: RVM can turn your life into a nightmare. Stick with RBENV. Follow the installation instructions in their GitHub page. https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: Just pointing out for others - after installing with Homebrew I found the path to export needed to be added to the bottom of .bash_profile, placing it at the top had no effect.

Answer (score 119):

**SHORT ANSWER:**

after installing ruby via homebrew just do this:

```
brew link --overwrite ruby
```

and restart or reopen your Terminal

---

**LONG ANSWER**

So I did a normal install of ruby using homebrew

```
brew install ruby
```

that installed fine BUT it was still using the system's default ruby.
which I verified by doing:

```
which ruby 
#/usr/bin/ruby
```

So as per Matthew Rudy's suggestion, I checked the order of my /etc/paths, and all was good.

Then I decided to do:

```
which -a ruby
#/usr/bin/ruby
#usr/local/bin/ruby
```

so nothing was broken as such.
tried to reinstall ruby again using the homebrew method, and then i found it.

Homebrew mentioned:

```
Warning: ruby-2.3.1 already installed, it's just not linked
```

so had to do:

```
brew link --overwrite ruby
```

Comment: Don't forget to restart your iTerm instance, otherwise `ruby --version` will show you an outdated version.

Comment: Do you actually need to restart? or just `hash -r`?

Comment: FYI, Homebrew now refuses do do it. For me with Fish, it suggested :

echo 'set -g fish_user_paths "/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin" $fish_user_paths' >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish

Comment: In my case, I had to add `--force`. `brew link --overwrite ruby --force`

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I really found it helpful.

Answer (score 48):

If you'd like to use homebrew to install 1.9.3, you can follow these steps:

```
$ brew update
$ brew install rbenv
$ brew install ruby-build
```

Once you have rbenv and ruby-build installed, you can run the following command to get Ruby 1.9.3 installed.

```
$ rbenv install 1.9.3-p125
```

Now if you’d like to use 1.9.3 by default, you can run the following command:

```
$ rbenv global 1.9.3-p125
```

Comment: The source link is dead now

Comment: Doesn't work on OS X 10.11+. The system keep using old version, and not the one I've installed/setted as default with rbenv install 1.9.3-p125 / rbenv global 1.9.3-p125

Comment: "rbenv global 1.9.3-p125" - this line saved my night. Thank!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. I had to put the path to the ruby exec in my $PATH before it worked.

Answer (score 11):

Ruby was installed by Homebrew at `/usr/local/opt/ruby`. So, we need to add this path to `bash` or `Zsh`.

```
# Type this to find out which shell you're using (e.g., bash, Zsh)
echo $SHELL

# If you're using Bash (e.g., echo $SHELL returns /bin/bash)
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

# If you're using Zsh
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

Then, source the file

```
# E.g., if you're using bash
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Finally, verify ruby's version

```
ruby -v
```

Comment: proper way for me. before you `echo` maybe run `echo $PATH` and see if any ruby was referred at all. I was setting up a new machine therefore no reference about ruby (via Brew) - the OS ruby does not need a separate reference. Till you add Brew/ruby to $PATH you will see `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin` is included in.

Answer (score 10):

I had similar situation. I installed ruby using Homebrew. `which -a ruby` gave me the following output:

```
#usr/local/bin/ruby
#/usr/bin/ruby
```

Which means that newly installed version should have been used, but `ruby --version` still returned the old system version.

I quit terminal (Cmd+Q), and after restart `ruby --version` returned the correct version. So make sure you restart terminal after installing before trying any other (potentially unnecessary) fixes.

Answer (score 5):

```
brew install ruby
```

This will install the latest version of ruby, now you want to set it as default use for example in my case:

```
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

then run

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

this will set it as default in the profile

now you can check the version of ruby

```
ruby -v
```

Answer (score 4):

**SHORT:**
Do note what you want to change it for.

If you're on OS X and trying to use Ruby for something like Jekyll, then don't use homebrew because that's what Apple is using for Ruby for and it might not be good to use if you're not sure what you're doing. Instead, use rbenv or RVM.

**LESS SHORT:**
I was trying to switch from the default version to an updated version (from 2.0) to use Jekyll because it required Ruby version 2.2.5 and above. I updated it and version 2.5 was installed, but when I checked "ruby -v", it was still 2.0. Once I finally got around to changing the default version, I wasn't able to install the package I needed because I didn't have write permission. For example, if you come across something like this, then you probably are having the same problem

```
$ gem install jekyll bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)    
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Answer (score 0):

In OSX you can change the path using:

sudo nano /etc/paths

And then add a path or change the order.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing [Craig Wayne's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37416716/15359960) I thought maybe I had missed a warning when installing ruby with Homebrew. So I reinstalled it with `brew reinstall ruby@2.7` and there it was:

```
==> Caveats
By default, binaries installed by gem will be placed into:
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/bin

You may want to add this to your PATH.

ruby@2.7 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have ruby@2.7 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find ruby@2.7 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/include"

For pkg-config to find ruby@2.7 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/lib/pkgconfig"
```

So the solution for me was adding `/usr/local/opt/ruby@2.7/bin:` to the beginning of PATH in `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score -2):

Just as an alternative approach for anyone else looking for an answer to this - you can set an alias in your .bash_profile e.g

```
ruby="/usr/local/bin/ruby"
```

this is how i got around the issue

Comment: yeah the problem with that (and most likely the reason of the downvotes) is that this only works if you want to manually invoke ruby and not have the system use a specific version