# Ruby installation issue using RVM

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I am having trouble installing Ruby using RVM. I had tried using readline and other suggestions online. None of the solutions worked.

I use Cygwin, Bash and have RVM installed.

```
rvm install 1.9.2
No binary rubies available for: /ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on    binary  rubies.
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make', please read /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/make.log
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p320, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p320 to /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/src/ruby-  1.9.2-p320
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #extracted to /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p320
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #configuring
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #compiling
ruby-1.9.2-p320 - #installing
ruby-1.9.2-p320 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320'
```

I see the below in the error log "/home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/make.log"

```
$ cat /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/make.log
CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd . && /bin/sh /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/missing --run aclocal-1.11
cd . && /bin/sh /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4/config/missing --run automake-1.11 --foreign
src/Makefile.am:2: Libtool library used but `LIBTOOL' is undefined
src/Makefile.am:2:   The usual way to define `LIBTOOL' is to add `LT_INIT'
src/Makefile.am:2:   to `configure.ac' and run `aclocal' and `autoconf' again.
src/Makefile.am:2:   If `LT_INIT' is in `configure.ac', make sure
src/Makefile.am:2:   its definition is in aclocal's search path.
Makefile:256: recipe for target `Makefile.in' failed
make: *** [Makefile.in] Error 1
```

Comment: "Please read /home/arvenkataraman/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/make.log". Well, did you read it? At least post it here.

Comment: [homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730676/how-can-i-switch-to-ruby-1-9-3-installed-using-homebrew) if it's an option

Answer (score 2):

This work for me make sure RVM is up to date

```
rvm get head

CC=/usr/bin/gcc rvm install 1.9.2 --enable-shared
```

note: /usr/bin/gcc ==> path/to/gcc

Comment: +1: this fix the problem for me; the hint helps me also for upgrading to ruby-2.0.0-p353;@Festus Tamakloe could you please add an explanation to understand how it works?

Answer (score 0):

few steps:

1. update RVM: `rvm get head`
2. read and follow instructions: `rvm requirements`
3. reinstall ruby: `rvm reinstall 1.9.2`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did not resolve my issue. I gave up on rvm and used mingw to install rails on my machine.