# Upgrading Mac Ruby through Homebrew (Mac OS 10.7)

Tags: ruby, macos

I'm having trouble setting up the compy 486 to use Ruby 1.9.3. I installed homebrew using _why's instructions (http://poignant.guide/book/expansion-pak-1.html) but when I check which version is installed it's still 1.8.7.

From what I understand this is because now there are two version of ruby installed. (See: [How can I switch to ruby 1.9.3 installed using Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730676/how-can-i-switch-to-ruby-1-9-3-installed-using-homebrew))

See:

```
Last login: Fri Feb 22 17:20:40 on ttys000
MacBook-Air:~ andrew$ brew install ruby
Error: ruby-1.9.3-p385 already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink ruby'
MacBook-Air:~ andrew$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin11.0]
MacBook-Air:~ andrew$
```

I read I should install Ruby Version Manger, but when I try that I get problems.

```
MacBook-Air:~ andrew$ $ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
-bash: $: command not found
```

So is there an easy way I can access my newer version of ruby 1.9.3 even if it's not used by default?

Comment: Your RVM installer command should be: `curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby` (you added "`$`" to the command; that just represented the command prompt) hence the `$: command not found` error.

Comment: I didn't realize you could run OS X on a Compy 486!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact you still get the system default Ruby even after installing a current version through Homebrew is a simple issue of `$PATH` definitions: OS X’ system Ruby is installed in `/usr/bin`, while Homebrew installs its version in `/usr/local/bin`, which, by default comes **after** `/usr/bin` in your `$PATH`.

To get the newly installed Ruby, specify the full binary path, i.e. `/usr/local/bin/ruby`. If you want to make that the default, you could, of course, use a Ruby version manager (*RVM* and *rbenv* being the best known ones), but simply altering your `$PATH` to put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` will do the trick too.

Comment: Homebrew now installs to `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/bin/ruby`. The above solution same can now be achieved by placing `/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.1/bin` first in the `$PATH` environment variable declaration.

Comment: Two remarks: one, to the best of my knowledge Homebrew has always installed the Ruby executable outside `/usr/local/bin`, the `ruby` found there being a symlink. Two, setting your path to the origin of the symlink I’d consider inadvisable, as that path is version dependent (the `2.6.1` bit), so you would have to update your `$PATH` definition every time Homebrew’s Ruby updates – hence the symlink and my recommendation in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you use rbenv (https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

rbenv is simpler and lighter than RVM, plus it is friendly to your system (RVM overrides the CD and GEM commands which is somewhat worrisome).

Once you install rbenv (I would use homebrew, directions on the rbenv github page linked above) you can do this magic:

```
rbenv install 1.9.3-p392
```

Note that because RVM overrides basic system commands you cannot have RVM and rbenv installed together.

Comment: Note that after you install rbenv you need to create ~/.rbenv/plugins and install ruby-build: https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build

Comment: the instructions on the wiki walk you through a homebrew install and includes commands to install ruby-build

Comment: Ok, I uninstalled RVM but having trouble with that last step.  --- unknown7c11be8d1064:~ andrew$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
unknown7c11be8d1064:~ andrew$ brew install rbenv
Error: rbenv-0.4.0 already installed         But, afterward: Downloading yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/36c852831d02cf90508c29852361d01b
Installing yaml-0.1.4...

BUILD FAILED
......... configure: error: in `/var/folders/y7/hf8_898n6mz4rn1c2121qqd80000gp/T/ruby-build.20130223180104.8873/yaml-0.1.4':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details

Comment: To be clear, I got through: $ brew update
$ brew install rbenv
$ brew install ruby-build, but get an error message when I use "rbenv install 1.9.3-p392".

Comment: can you post the contents of config.log?