# Getting Load error -- watir-webdriver on Mac Yosemite

Tags: ruby, macos, watir-webdriver, rubymine-7

I have Ruby 2.2.2, I have already watir-webdriver gem installed, when I run following script

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

It gives in

```
`require': cannot load such file -- watir-webdriver(LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I have rubymine 7.1.2

Here is my gem list

```
$ gem list
```

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bundler (1.10.3)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
childprocess (0.5.6)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
ffi (1.9.8)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
multi_json (1.11.1)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rubyzip (1.1.7)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
selenium-webdriver (2.46.2)
watir-webdriver (0.7.0)
websocket (1.2.2)
yard (0.8.7.6)

Please suggest what to do?

Comment: Did you try to opened irb in terminal and `require 'watir-webdriver'` without any other gems?

Comment: it's interesting, you say that you have ruby v. 2.2.2, but, log of your error say that it was searching in directory ruby 2.0.0, can you use command: ruby -v and add here what it show?

Comment: Janhavis-MacBook-Pro:~ janhavideshpande$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin14]

Answer (score 0):

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/...` is the [system library in OS X Yosemite](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29795).

Ruby 2.2 (or any other version) is installed by you or some other user -- perhaps via RVM, given you have some rvm gem installed? If so you need to [use RVM to change the default](https://rvm.io/rubies/default). If you did not install RVM correctly or ignored some warning or command it gave to you, you might want to re-install.

If you did not install Ruby 2.2 via RVM*, here are [instructions for changing OS X default Ruby installed using Brew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8731098/1651458).

(*I could not recommend RVM more strongly. Other people like rbenv to do the same job.)