# I installed Ruby 2.5.0 but it's showing previous version only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I have Ruby 2.6.8p205 and I installed, 2.5.0

By command

```
brew install ruby@2.5

By default, binaries installed by gem will be placed into:

    /opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin

You may want to add this to your PATH.

ruby is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew,
because macOS already provides this software and installing another version in
parallel can cause all kinds of trouble.

If you need to have ruby first in your PATH, run:
  

    echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find ruby you may need to set:

    export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib"

    export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/include"

For pkg-config to find ruby you may need to set:
  
    export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"
```

But I run

```
ruby -v
```

It still showing

```
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart your shell

Comment: This question was confusing. You told readers "You may want to add this to your PATH" and "ruby is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /opt/homebrew". In fact these are items in console output that the computer was telling you, but they were (un)formatted to make it seem like you were saying them. I have tried to repair this in your post.

Comment: I was facing the same problem and resloved by following this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37511503/5145150

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to use a ruby version manager like rvm or rbenv, they will make your life so much easier.

To solve the current issue though, can you try `brew link ruby@2.5` and see if that solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest a ruby version manager, I personally use asdf, if you choose to go with asdf the commands are fairly simple.

1. To install your desired version - `asdf install ruby <version>`
2. Check to see if you're using that version `ruby -v`
3. If you are not using the correct one `asdf global ruby <version>`
4. Also make sure you're using the ruby in your shims with `which ruby`