# make ruby default to 3.1.2 on macOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on macOS.

```
brew upgrade ruby
Warning: ruby 3.1.2 already installed
```

but doing

```
ruby -v
```

would get me

```
ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.arm64e-darwin20]
```

I tried

```
whereis ruby
```

and it is giving me

```
/usr/bin/ruby
```

I want version 3.1.2 to appear when doing `ruby -v`, but I ran out of idea on how to make my machine default to version 3.1.2 . Any suggestion?

Comment: Use `rbenv`? That's the usual thing... Homebrew installs it but initializing and configuring it is up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier if you use a ruby version manager like rbenv or rvm

```
brew install rbenv 
rbenv install 3.1.2
rbenv use 3.1.2
```

Otherwise, you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8731098/14473816

**Edit:**

As Prince Radebe said:

You need to use `rbenv local 3.1.2` instead of `rbenv use 3.1.2`

Comment: There is no such command as ‘rbenv use.’

Comment: Its rbenv local 3.1.2