# how to solve "ruby installation is missing psych" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm

I used rvm to install ruby 1.9.3. even though it was successfully installed, it complained about libyaml. and now every time i wanna install a gem (say rails) this warning shows up:

```
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output). To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

I use Mac os X 10.7 (Lion).

Comment: Have you tried to install libyaml following these instructions: http://pyyaml.org/wiki/LibYAML ?

Comment: Are you using homebrew? Try `brew doctor`. Does it list a problem with libyaml link?

Comment: Mac users: `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/ && brew reinstall ruby` as stated in the official [homebrew-core](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core) Gtihub resolved [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11636#issuecomment-290892884)

Answer (score 241, accepted):

In my case

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
```

and

```
rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p125
```

solved the problem.

For people using Ubuntu, make sure that `libtool` is installed prior to the steps above:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

For macOS users (with homebrew):

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/ && brew reinstall ruby
```

Comment: You actually mean:
`rvm package install libyaml`

Comment: No, he meant `rvm pkg install libyaml`.  From `rvm usage`: `pkg :: Install a dependency package {readline,iconv,zlib,openssl}`.

Comment: I think it depends on what version of rvm you use. In rvm 1.6.9 it is `package`.

Comment: didn't help for job in Jenkins.

Comment: After running `rvm pkg install libyaml` it recommends to reinstall all rubies with `rvm reinstall all --force`. It might be useful if you have more than one.

Comment: Should you use ruby-head or explicity write the version number?

Comment: You might have to do `sudo rvm pkg install libyaml` if you get errors such as `Error running 'tar xmzf /Users/Kieran/.rvm/archives/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz -C /Users/Kieran/.rvm/src ', please read /Users/Kieran/.rvm/log/yaml/extract.log`. This is because for some reason it doesn't have permissions to remove folders and replace them.

Comment: Had to do  `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-libyaml-dir=/home/rails/.rvm/usr` as suggested in http://serverfault.com/questions/442150/how-to-fix-ruby-installation-is-missing-psych-for-yaml-output-on-centos

Comment: Sometimes a question deserves a question, not an assumptive answer, to get at the root problem. In my case, I got a very similar error when doing `gem install jekyll`. My rvm commands were also giving me errors. I had recently upgraded to Mavericks. I think that broke some of the brew links, including libyaml. I did also reinstall rvm and ruby as well, but I'm not convinced that was an essential part of the solution. I believe resolving all the `brew doctor` issues, especially the `brew link --overwrite libyaml` fixed it for me.

Comment: rvm dpkg depricated.  Use rvm autolibs

Comment: thx :) but `rvm pkg` was deprecated, `rvm autolibs` was recommended :)

Comment: I instead allowed rvm to handle everything and did `rvm requirements`. That solved the problem.

Comment: For version 3.0.0 `rvm reinstall ruby-3.0.0-p0`

Comment: No binary rubies available for: osx/12.6/arm64/ruby-1.9.3-p125

Answer (score 31):

```
brew install libyaml
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Is what worked for me (on Snow Leopard).

Comment: I had to do this as well. rvm pkg install libyaml didn't do it for me.

Comment: I only needed the first line, then trying again worked (I'm using rbenv)

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. On RHEL: `sudo dnf install libyaml-devel`

Answer (score 22):

for ubuntu and rvm

```
sudo apt-get install libtool
rvm pkg install libyaml
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

worked

Comment: I had to 'rvm uninstall all' before installing libyaml. That's the only way the error cleared

Answer (score 20):

If not using rvm, but rather you are building and installing ruby 1.9.3 from scratch — for example, you're managing your ruby versions with [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) — you must install libyaml first. Get it from http://pyyaml.org/; at the moment, the file you want is http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz. Open the tarball and cd into the resulting folder. Then:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

You are now ready to build ruby. Download ruby from http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/. Open the tarball and cd into the resulting folder. Now:

```
./configure --prefix=/wherever/you/want/it/to/go
make
make install
```

(Or possibly `sudo make install`, depending on where you're putting it.) If using rbenv, you'll know it has worked if you switch to `rbenv global 1.9.3-p194` (or whatever your version is called) and `gem --version` works without a warning. That worked for me on Mac OS X 10.6.8. (**Update**: I just tried this on Mac OS X 10.8.1 and it seems to have worked fine there too.)

Comment: what should gem --version output? I installed Ruby 1.9.3-p327 but gem --version outputs 1.8.23 (not sure if that's related) and when I do bundle update, it strangely says that some gems are requiring => 1.9.2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116083/1-9-3-installed-error-message-factory-girl-requires-ruby-version-1-9-2

Comment: your `gem --version` sounds correct, but maybe you've got your path munged because of former use of rvm

Comment: And if you must install yaml without sudo, specify a prefix other than `/usr/local` when configuring yaml, then configure ruby with `--with-opt-dir=/path/to/yaml/prefix --with-yaml --prefix=/path/to/ruby/prefix`

Comment: I know this is over a year old, but the question was about an error with RVM.  How could starting with "If not using rvm" be appropiate?

Answer (score 9):

In my case the solution was to add the `psych` gem to the Gemfile.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem. libyaml wouldn't compile. It turns out I was missing libtool.

```
yum install libtool
yum install libyaml (or rvm pkg install libyaml)
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

That solved my problem.

Comment: No package libtool available. Nothing to do.

Comment: centos can't yum install libtool? not believe it.. are u using non-redhat based system and need to apt-get?

Comment: @phil88530 old version of CentOS can be more stupid than you think

Comment: @DennisCheung oh ok, never played with an old one

Answer (score 6):

If you have installed ruby on macOS with homebrew, [try this solution](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11636#issuecomment-290892884).

`rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/ && brew reinstall ruby`

Note that this will get rid of all installed gems. Best save a list of installed gems with `gem list` before you run this.

Comment: But `gem list` is what causes the error in the first place (for me).

Answer (score 5):

```
$ brew doctor
$ brew link libyaml
```

Comment: Resolving all `brew doctor` issues fixed it for me. I got an error very similar to the questioner's error while trying to `gem install jekyll`. All commands through rvm were giving errors too. The underlying and not so obvious problem is that homebrew, I'm assuming the means by which rvm installs stuff, was having issues. I had recently upgraded to Mavericks on Mac OS. In my case, resolving all the `brew doctor` issues eliminated every single error message. Now everything is working smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me on Ubuntu:
- installing libyaml-dev (sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev)
- installing rvm + ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 4):

I reinstalled ruby 1.9.3 with libyaml support:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-libyaml
```

I made sure that I would use 1.9.3 before installing psych:

```
rvm use 1.9.3
```

I installed psych:

```
gem install psych
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this fixed finally. The issue was that even though I installed libyaml with brew, it was never linked. I had to remove a conflicting header file and then `brew link libyaml`.

Answer (score 4):

Installing ruby with rvm for mac osx, use autolibs to install libyaml and first uninstalling libyaml helps.

This worked for me:

```
brew uninstall libyaml
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.1
```

Comment: Thanks @user33302. Above solution also worked for me on Mac OS EI CAPITON.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem (Lion 10.7.4), and fixed it by upgrading rvm then reinstalling ruby

1) upgrade rvm https://rvm.io//rvm/install/

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

2) Then use rvm to reinstall ruby 1.9.3 (which had been previously installed with the earlier version of rvm)

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Answer (score 3):

On CentOS 6.3 none of the above worked. However installing **libyaml** from source *before* installing ruby resolved the problem.

```
$ wget http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
$ tar xzvf yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
$ cd yaml-0.1.4
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

and then

```
rvm install 1.9.3
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 3):

For problems with `rbenv` on `ubuntu 22`, I had to installl `libtool` and `libffi-dev` through apt, and compile the yaml package (Thanks to Dmitry for his answer):

```
sudo apt install libtool
sudo apt install libffi-dev

wget https://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.2.5.tar.gz
tar zxf yaml-0.2.5.tar.gz
cd yaml-0.2.5
./configure
make
make install
```

After that, I ran `rbenv install 3.2.2` again and it worked.

Comment: `sudo apt install libyaml-dev` solved it for me (Ruby 3.2.2 on Ubuntu 22.04.3). Manually installing yaml-0.2.5 was not needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo port install libyaml # or brew install libyaml
rvm get latest
rvm pkg install iconv
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=~/.rvm/usr --with-iconv-dir=~/.rvm/usr

curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75414/linecache19-0.5.13.gem
curl -OL http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/75415/ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem

gem install linecache19-0.5.13.gem ruby-debug-base19-0.11.26.gem -- --with-ruby-include=$rvm_path/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125/
gem install ruby-debug19

rvm reload
```

reload your .rvmrc (cd out, cd in)

```
bundle
```

Answer (score 2):

None of these answers worked for me.

I found my answer on https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build/issues/119
I am on Centos 6.3 Virtual Machine.

YOU MUST install libyaml before you install ruby. IF you ALREADY installed ruby you must get rid of the files before compiling source again!!!

```
# cd to your ruby source location
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby # clean out ruby files
./configure
make && make install
gem -v # check if error is fixed
```

Answer (score 2):

I built the libyaml files separately from source and installed them in /usr/local/lib. The ruby that RVM created still did not see them, and rather than muck with the makefile or the system LD_LIBRARY_PATH I just copied /usr/local/lib/libyaml* to ~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/

That quieted the warning.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all of these answers and still wasn't able to get it working. I installed libyaml with homebrew and then installed Ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 with rvm. Each time it complained that I was missing psych (libyaml). But trying to install libyaml told me it was already installed. Rinse, repeat. Urgh.

Finally, what I did was to *uninstall* libyaml. Then I [enabled autolibs in rvm](https://rvm.io/rvm/autolibs/), which (at least in OSX) allows rvm to install and manage dependencies more directly. Now when I installed the Rubies, rvm was able to install libyaml and recognize that it was in the right spot.

So if you've tried all of the other options, try actually *removing* libyaml and then installing your Rubies. It's count-intuitive from the error messages, but that's what finally worked for me.

Comment: You don't need libyaml: you need libyaml-dev, which is what rvm installs for you with --autolibs

Answer (score 2):

If you are building ruby from source (I built 1.9.3 on Fedora 20), you will need this before you do the configure/make to build ruby:

```
yum install libyaml-devel
```

(in addition to yum install libyaml.)  Similar to Francis's answer using rpmforge above.

Comment: Also confirmed on Centos 5.6

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (*Cent OS 5.7*), none of the above solutions worked to me.

```
// My console warning
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

After doing several re-installs, I realized it's looking for yaml in ruby version of `1.9.1` instead of `1.9.3`. So i downgraded

```
// obviously after installing `libyaml`
rvm remove all
rvm install 1.9.1
rvm use 1.9.1 --default
```

And it worked 8D!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using

> rvm 1.16.20 (version) by Wayne E. Seguin ,
>   Michal Papis  [https://rvm.io/]

and also got the following error during bundle install

> .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `': It seems
>   your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output). To
>   eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your
>   ruby.

Here are three different ways to resolve this error w/o having to gem install psych

1. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
2. alter /etc/ld.so.conf

   > ```
   > sudo su - root
   > echo /usr/local/lib64 >> /etc/ld.so.conf
   > echo /usr/local/lib >> /etc/ld.so.conf
   > ldconfig
   > ```
3. Fix rvm ruby 1.9.3 installation via

   > ```
   > patch .rvm/scripts/functions/manage/ruby < ruby-1.9.3-LDFLAGS.patch
   > rvm uninstall ruby-1.9.3-p194
   > export LDFLAGS='-L /usr/local/lib64 -L/usr/local/lib -Xlinker -R/usr/local/lib64 -Xlinker -R/usr/local/lib'
   > rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194 --disable-binary
   > grep configure_args .rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194/config.log # to confirm LDFLAG
   > ```

```
    $ diff  -c .rvm/{src/rvm/,}scripts/functions/manage/ruby
    *** .rvm/src/rvm/scripts/functions/manage/ruby  2012-11-10 06:28:14.000000000 +0000
    --- .rvm/scripts/functions/manage/ruby  2013-01-25 17:18:00.000000000 +0000
    ***************
    *** 106,123 ****
              # when relative is in effect libyaml is installed in ruby itself so it will be moved with ruby
              prefix_path="${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}" libyaml

    !         __rvm_update_configure_env CFLAGS="-I${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}/include"
    !         __rvm_update_configure_env LDFLAGS="-L${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}/lib"
              if [[ -d "${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}/lib64" ]]
    !         then __rvm_update_configure_env LDFLAGS="-L${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}/lib64"
              fi
            else
              libyaml_installed || libyaml # Installs libyaml

    !         __rvm_update_configure_env CFLAGS="-I${rvm_path}/usr/include"
    !         __rvm_update_configure_env LDFLAGS="-L${rvm_path}/usr/lib"
              if [[ -d "${rvm_path}/usr/lib64" ]]
    !         then __rvm_update_configure_env LDFLAGS="-L${rvm_path}/usr/lib64"
              fi
            fi

    --- 106,123 ----
              # when relative is in effect libyaml is installed in ruby itself so it will be moved with ruby
              prefix_path="${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}" libyaml

    !         __rvm_update_configure_env CFLAGS="-I${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}/include ${CFLAGS}"
    !         __rvm_update_configure_env LDFLAGS="-L${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}/lib ${LDFLAGS}"
              if [[ -d "${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}/lib64" ]]
    !         then __rvm_update_configure_env LDFLAGS="-L${rvm_rubies_path}/${rvm_ruby_string}/lib64 ${LDFLAGS}"
              fi
            else
              libyaml_installed || libyaml # Installs libyaml

    !         __rvm_update_configure_env CFLAGS="-I${rvm_path}/usr/include ${CFLAGS}"
    !         __rvm_update_configure_env LDFLAGS="-L${rvm_path}/usr/lib ${LDFLAGS}"
              if [[ -d "${rvm_path}/usr/lib64" ]]
    !         then __rvm_update_configure_env LDFLAGS="-L${rvm_path}/usr/lib64 ${LDFLAGS}"
              fi
            fi
```

Comment: I've confirmed this patch is not needed if you are using the latest stable rvm version 1.18.4

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with the same failures with `rvm install ruby-2.0.0` for many, MANY hours. I had tried all the different methods to install libyaml; `wget source`, `yum` and `rvm`. I also tried all of the different approaches listed in similar threads. Because I tried all the different methods, I had multiple installations and locations of libyaml.

RVM is perfectly capable of installing the necessary dependencies in `~/.rvm`. Simply removing the libyaml files from non-RVM install fixed this issue for me:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libyaml*.*

rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p0
```

Works!

Answer (score 1):

NON-RVM ruby install method.

```
% uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Feb 22 00:31:26 UTC 2013  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

% cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.4 (Final)

% wget http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/dag/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
% sudo rpm -K rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.*.rpm"
% sudo rpm -ivh rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.*.rpm"
```

DISABLE rpmforge by editing this file and set   enabled=0
    % sudo vi /etc/yum.repos.d/rpmforge.repo

```
% grep rpmforge ~/.aliases
alias rpmforge "sudo yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='rpmforge'"

% rpmforge install libyaml libyaml-devel

% sudo yum list installed | grep libyaml
libyaml.x86_64          0.1.4-1.el5.rf  @rpmforge                               
libyaml-devel.x86_64    0.1.4-1.el5.rf  @rpmforge
```

The libyaml-devel is the key.

```
% tar zxvf ruby-1.9.3-p448.tar.gz
% cd ruby-1.9.3-p448
% ./configure -prefix=$HOME/ruby-1.9.3-p448
% make ; make install
% cd $HOME; ln -s ./ruby-1.9.3-p448 ruby
```

Update your path and source .cshrc

```
% echo $PATH
/home/francis/ruby/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/francis/bin:/home/francis/jdk1.7.0_25/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

% which ruby
/home/francis/ruby/bin/ruby

% gem update --system
```

Set your GEM_HOME in .cshrc and source

```
% echo $GEM_HOME
% /home/francis/ruby/lib/ruby/gems

% gem install mysql2 pg ruby-debug-ide rails capistrano capistrano-ext passenger
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this error and noticed I had different versions of Ruby installed with HomeBrew, along with many gems that I no longer used. So did a full clean up like this:

```
$ brew remove --force ruby # remove all versions installed
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby # remove all gems and leftover files
$ brew install ruby
$ gem install bundler
$ bundle install
```

If you don't use a `Gemfile`, make sure you know which gems to reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

In my case [all I needed to do](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11636#issuecomment-289433135) was

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/psych-2.2.4
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.4.0/psych-2.2.4
```

Now, FWIW, `gem list` includes

```
psych (2.2.4, default: 2.2.2)
```

Comment: I am on macOS Sierra, and this worked for me. It is the same solution reported in this GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/11636) Try this solution first as it is much simpler and less drastic than the others in this page.

Answer (score 1):

- Ubuntu
- Using RVM
- Reason: Conflicting Psych gem versions between ruby 2.4.4 and ruby 2.5.1

I spent a few hours trying to get my error to go away and none of the replies here suited my case, so I thought I would post how I solved it...

In my case when I ran `gem list | grep psych`, I had the following output: `psych(default: 3.1.0, default: 3.0.2)`.

Apparently since version 2.5.0, ruby depends on the newer version of psych (3.1.0) and having both set as default was messing up everything. Notice that I never ended up finding out why those were both set as default - I completely wiped out rvm and ruby versions from my computer due to this.

So in order to remove the older version (3.0.2) from being set as default, head to `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-x.x.x@global/specifications/default`. If you run `ls | grep psych` it will return both versions of the gem here. If you want to maintain 3.1.0 as default just run `mv psych-3.0.2.gemspec ../` and then try running `gemlist` to make sure it is listing only one version as default now...

tl;dr
`cd /.rvm/gems/ruby-x.x.x@global/specifications/default`
`mv psych-3.0.2 ../`

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

On Snow Leopard, the solution by Catharz did not work for me. This solution, however, did:

```
brew install libyaml
rvm get head
rvm reinstall 1.9.3  --with-gcc=clang
```

(The rvm reinstall gave me a warning about clang not having the option "--with-libyaml" but it solved the error message regardless.)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me at least on Ubuntu 10.04

$ sudo apt-get install libtool

$ rvm reinstall 1.9.3

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris:

```
# sudo crle -64 -l /usr/local/lib
```

to add `/usr/local/lib` to the shared library search path
(see man crle)

Comment: This question about os x.

Answer (score 0):

When I switch from 64 bit to 32 bit on Snow Leopard 10.6.8, I had reinstalled ruby (used rvm) to run on 32bit and met the same problem. So I just 'cleanup' all thing that cached by rvm before and problems solved. Hope this tip can help someone.

> rvm cleanup all
>
> rvm install ruby_version_here  //(This way, rvm will also re-download newest yaml).

BTW, if you still meet this problem, I think you can try:

> gem install psych

Answer (score 0):

For those with Mountain Lion and RVM version >= 1.18.x

RVM ships with this new tool that is used as a flag when installing ruby versions. It's called autolibs.

I got rid of this psych problem by doing the following:

`rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p392 --autolibs=3`

Read the help text BEFORE by doing:

`rvm help autolibs`

Cool.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem after OSX upgrade, this what solves my problem:

```
   brew rm libyaml
   brew cleanup libyaml
   brew install libyaml
   brew rm openssl
   brew cleanup openssl
   brew install openssl
   rvm remove *your version*
   rvm install *latest version*
```

[found here](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/4513843-error-running-gemset_reset_env-ruby-2-1-3)

Answer (score 0):

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
$LIBYAML_PATH will be the path where RVM installs the upated yaml
rvm get stable
rvm reinstall all --force --with-libyaml-dir=$LIBYAML_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue. I'm using MacPorts with `rbenv` installed!

What I did:

1. `sudo port install ruby26`
2. `sudo port select --set ruby ruby26` (this effectively takes macOS default ruby installation out of game)
3. removed all gems from `~/.gem/ruby/2.6.0/gems` which caused errors while invoking the `gem` command
4. run `gem pristine` commands for all gems listed by gem list (the exact commands are part of the warnings)
5. finally `gem update --user-install`