# Fixing the "ruby installation is missing psych" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, yaml, psych

I'm running Ruby ruby 1.9.3p125 and I keep getting this error which is making it impossible for me to do any kind of development in Rails.

> It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output). To
>   eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your
>   ruby.

I've Googled around and tried seemingly everything but nothing seems to be working. I'm really eager to start on some new projects but can't seem to get around this hurdle.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious, have you installed libyaml and reinstalled ruby?

Comment: Yes I have. Downloaded, configured, did a Make command, reinstalled Ruby. Didn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had same problem after installing ruby 1.9.3 with rvm.
I solve it by downloading *yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz* into ~/.rvm/archives and then reinstalled ruby again.

```
cd ~/.rvm/archives
wget http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

If you get some compileerrors, try with this instead

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

Answer (score 8):

for ubuntu 64 bit nothing was working, but finally when I installed

libyaml-dev using

`sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev`

everything worked even with reinstalling ruby

Answer (score 6):

The error message is a little confusing.

For `Ubuntu Linux` try installing

```
sudo apt-get install libyaml-dev
```

Or for `openSuSE Linux` run

```
sudo zypper install libyaml-devel
```

then re-compile & re-install Ruby and you should be good to go.

A couple of points, though -- run `make clean` to remove old compiled files.  Then run `sudo make install` to ensure you have proper permissions for system level installs.  Finally, you might get some "file 'lib' not found" errors... ignore these.  Rails seems to work just fine.

Comment: I'm on OS X Lion, does that matter?

Comment: I assume that even on OS X Lion libyaml is just the compiled lib itself while libyaml-dev provides the headers to the lib.

Answer (score 1):

You need libyaml to be present at the time that Ruby 1.9.3 is built. See my answer here, describing the process (without rvm):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12361446/341994

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution to this for me was `brew install libyaml`. In my case I got the message:

> Warning: libyaml-0.1.6_1 already installed, it's just not linked

So, `brew link libyaml` produced

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/libyaml/0.1.6_1... 5 symlinks created

Done. This assumes you have homebrew, which you should. If you don't, install it thusly:

`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

...and then start at the top here. Cheers!