# New to Rails: Need help troubleshooting an error thats preventing me from entering anything in my terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, message

Pretty much anything I try and enter into terminal returns the following request.  Can anyone help me please?

ie:

Davids-MacBook-Pro:omrails Lobo$ `gem install bundler`

```
/Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 7 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:253:in `load_file'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `new'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/gem:30:in `<main>'
Davids-MacBook-Pro:omrails Lobo$ grm
-bash: grm: command not found
Davids-MacBook-Pro:omrails Lobo$ gem
/Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 7 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:203:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:151:in `parse'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:127:in `load'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:253:in `load_file'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb:191:in `initialize'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `new'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:78:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:51:in `run'
    from /Users/Lobo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/gem:30:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably an issue with your .gemrc

See this post: [Having trouble installing any ruby 1.9.x (with rbenv) on mac osx due to psych YAML parse errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553887/having-trouble-installing-any-ruby-1-9-x-with-rbenv-on-mac-osx-due-to-psych-ya)