# I am trying to install Rails on Mac however it wont let me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railsinstaller

I am trying to install Rails on my Mac however everytime i try to install it I receive this:

```
$ gem install rails

/Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:369:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 4 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:369:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:317:in `parse'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:244:in `load'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:332:in `load_file'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:197:in `initialize'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
    from /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

I have searched hours trying to figure this out so any help would be greatly appreciated. I take it this is a simple fix, so apologize in advance for this easy question.

Comment: Try the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553887/having-trouble-installing-any-ruby-1-9-x-with-rbenv-on-mac-osx-due-to-psych-ya

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you are using newer version of ruby i.e *2.1.0* which was just released today and the relevant gems for **rails** are not fully compatible with it.

You can install **rails** in **ruby 2.0.0** through **RMV** i.e

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0
$ rvm use 2.0.0
$ ruby -v 
# should retrun 2.0.0-p...
$ gem install rails
```

Comment: thank you for this. i tried installing 2.0.0 and it came back with:Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0:/Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global:/Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0:/Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global GEM_HOME=/Users/macbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0 /Users/macbook/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby -d /Users/macbook/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.1.11/setup.rb',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/macbook/.rvm/log/1388034184_ruby-2.0.0-p353/rubygems.install.log