# Rails Error - Psych::SyntaxError - YAML

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, syntax-error, yaml

This is my first rails app so any help is greatly appreciated. I've been working on the app for a few weeks and just started running into errors when running bundle install.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse':   (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 29 (Psych::SyntaxError)
```

I can post the full trace if it will help. I validated the .yml files using yamllint and the script in this post [rails error, couldn't parse YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980877/rails-error-couldnt-parse-yaml)

```
require 'yaml'

d = Dir["./**/*.yml"]
d.each do |file|
  begin
    puts "checking : #{file}"
    f =  YAML.load_file(file)
  rescue Exception
    puts "failed to read #{file}: #{$!}"
  end
end
```

Rails Console output:

```
2.1.5p273 :001 > load 'yamlerrors.rb'
checking : ./test/fixtures/comments.yml
checking : ./test/fixtures/posts.yml
checking : ./test/fixtures/users.yml
checking : ./config/database.yml
checking : ./config/secrets.yml
checking : ./config/locales/en.yml
=> true
```

Any other suggestions where to look? I've tried looking at the .gemrc file as mentioned here [Having trouble installing any ruby 1.9.x (with rbenv) on mac osx due to psych YAML parse errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553887/having-trouble-installing-any-ruby-1-9-x-with-rbenv-on-mac-osx-due-to-psych-ya) but don't have one. I am developing in Cloud9 with PostgreSQL. I think the issue started when I tried to connect to AWS in production using Fog.

Comment: I couldn't resolve the issue so ended up copying the app to a clean environment. This appears o have resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and resolved it by removing the extra spaces in the yml file.