# No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320

Tags: ruby, rvm

There's a two year old blog post [here](http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/11/26%20/fixing-the-you-have-to-install-development-tools-first-error-with-nokogiri/) explaining how to fix the error 'you 'have to install development tools first' error that comes with Nokogiri, a problem that arises if you upgrade to Mountain Lion after having installed RVM. In the blog post he says you have to  do

```
rvm update head
rvm --force install 1.9.2
gem install bundle

## in your rails app
bundle
Installing nokogiri (1.4.2) with native extensions
 ...
```

`rvm update head` has now changed to `rvm get head`.  However, after that I **blindly** did

```
rvm --force install 1.9.2
```

and got this error message

```
rvm --force install 1.9.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
The provided compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
  [1]: http://www.fakingfantastic.com/2010/11/26 /fixing-the-you-have-to-install-development-tools-first-error-with-nokogiri/
```

In other words, it directed me back to the same blog post.

Looking at RVM website, I blindly did

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

I got this error

ruby-1.9.2-p320 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320'

Following its instructions, I did  rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320 and got the same binaries error

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.2-p320.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
The provided compiler '/usr/bin/gcc' is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.
```

Can anyone provide some guidance

Comment: This is more of a http://superuser.com/ question.

Comment: Of course if you really want my recommendation, I'd say jump ship and use rbenv instead of rvm. I've posted instructions on how to build ruby 1.9.3 with rbenv on Mountain Lion.

Comment: @matt I did rvm list known. When I tried to use one, rvm use 1.9.2, it gave me the error saying it wasn't installed, and when I tried to install, it gave me the binary rubies error message

Comment: @Matt where are those instructions? I'll have a look

Comment: For example http://stackoverflow.com/a/12361446/341994

Comment: And http://www.apeth.com/nonblog/stories/ruby193.html

Comment: Using a two year old page to help you use RVM, which is very quickly changing program, is not likely to work well. Your best bet is to read through rvm.io and here on SO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to run:

```
rvm get head
rvm autolibs enable
rvm use --install 1.9.2
bundle install
```

Comment: As @mpapis mentioned and AS THE MESSAGE TOLD YOU TO DO, read ```rvm requirements```

Answer (score 1):

firstly, Install "Command line Tools" from inside Xcode after you'll be good to install "RVM Requirements" and Ruby.