# Installing ruby 1.9.2 with RVM on Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to install ruby 1.9.2 using RVM and I cannot seem to get it to work. I have installed homebrew, GCC 4.2, X-Code command line tools, and I've made sure I have all the rvm requirements and that RVM is up to date. It just will not work. Here is a gist of what I am seeing in my terminal. Thank you very much.

Terminal:
https://gist.github.com/justinhenricks/5264924

Configure.log file:
https://gist.github.com/justinhenricks/5264973

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14114976/no-binary-rubies-available-for-osx-10-8-x86-64-ruby-1-9-2-p320

Comment: This does not help me. I have installed RVM requirements. I also have GCC 4.2 in usr/bin, which is not LLVM based. I also just tried rvm --force install 1.9.2 with the exact same behavior. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: `checking whether the C compiler works... no`

Comment: please also include output from: `rvm get head; rvm install 1.9.2 --debug`