# 1.9.3 installed, error message factory_girl requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I just installed rbenv with ruby 1.9.3

```
rbenv version
1.9.3-p327 (set by /Users/me/.rbenv/version)
```

However, when I tried to run bundle update (inside a project that was created before rbenv was installed), I got an error message that factory_girl required at least ruby 1.9.2. See error message below

If it's relevant, when I do gem --version, I see a reference to 1.8.23.

```
gem --version
1.8.23
```

Error message

```
Installing factory_girl (4.1.0) /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:163:in `install': factory_girl requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2. (Gem::InstallError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/cli.rb:268:in `update'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.18/bin/bundle:13
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:19
```

Update:

The first answer told me to do three steps

```
gem install bundle
rbenv rehash
bundle install
```

I did those steps (it installed bundler) '

```
gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.2.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.2.3
1 gem installed
```

but when I tried 'bundle install, I got the same error message about Factory_girl. Interestingly, I decided to try those three steps again, beginning with gem install bunlder, and it installed it again?!#??

Answer (score 4):

The `bundle` command you are using is from system Ruby installation which is Ruby 1.8.x.

Try

1. `gem install bundler`
2. `rbenv rehash`
3. `bundle install`

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I followed your steps but got the same result. Interestingly, after I got the same results, I tried your steps again (just to be sure) and it 'gem install bunlder' installed bundler a second time, which doesn't make sense to me. It shouln't need to install it again should it?

Comment: Have no idea, maybe there is something wrong with your rbenv environment. Are you using zsh or bash on your Mac?