# SQLException on db:test:load with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, database-schema

I've been working on a small but somewhat complex Rails application with multiple has_and_belongs_to_many relationships.  It's open source, and the code is [here](https://github.com/OAGr/fermihub).  Everything was working fine, but recently I added a new HABTM relationship migration, and an rspec test started to fail.  Rake:db:migrate was working (and the issue was working locally), just not in testing.  Upon running db:test:load --trace , I get the following error:

> :fermi og$ rake db:test:load --trace /Users/og/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in
>   `<top (required)>': It seems your ruby installation is missing psych
>   (for YAML output). To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml
>   and reinstall your ruby.
>   ** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
>   ** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
>   ** Invoke environment (first_time)
>   ** Execute environment
>   ** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
>   ** Execute db:load_config
>   ** Execute db:test:purge
>   ** Execute db:test:load
>   ** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
>   ** Invoke db:test:purge 
>   ** Execute db:test:load_schema
>   ** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
>   ** Invoke environment 
>   ** Invoke db:load_config 
>   ** Execute db:schema:load rake aborted! SQLite3::SQLException: object name reserved for internal use: sqlite_sp_functions: CREATE TABLE
>   "sqlite_sp_functions" ("name" text, "text" text) 
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`
>   initialize'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in
>   `new'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in`
>   prepare'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in`
>   block in execute'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in `block in log'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in `log'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:278:in`
>   execute'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:170:in
>   `create_table'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in`block in method_missing'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in`
>   measure'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in`method_missing' /Users/og/Documents/websites/fermi/db/schema.rb:49:in
>   `block in <top (required)>'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/schema.rb:50:in`
>   instance_eval'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/schema.rb:50:in
>   `define' /Users/og/Documents/websites/fermi/db/schema.rb:14:in`'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in
>   `load'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`
>   block in load'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in
>   `load_dependency'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activesupport-3.2.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`
>   load'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:388:in
>   `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in`
>   call'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in
>   `block in execute'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in
>   `invoke'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:499:in`
>   block (3 levels) in '
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in
>   `call'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in`
>   block in execute'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in`
>   execute'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in
>   `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in`
>   mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in
>   `invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in`
>   invoke'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:479:in
>   `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in`
>   call'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in
>   `block in execute'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in
>   `execute'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in`
>   block in invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in
>   `mon_synchronize'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in`
>   invoke_with_call_chain'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in
>   `invoke'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in`
>   invoke_task'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in
>   `block (2 levels) in top_level'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in`
>   each'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in
>   `block in top_level'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in`
>   run_with_threads'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in
>   `top_level'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in`
>   block in run'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in
>   `standard_exception_handling'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in`
>   run'
>   /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/bin/rake:33:in
>   `<top (required)>' /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/rake:23:in`
>   load' /Users/og/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-head/bin/rake:23:in `'
>   Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load

My schema.rb file is the following:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended to check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20130519192155) do

  create_table "distributions", :force => true do |t|
    t.float    "mean"
    t.float    "spread"
    t.float    "wideness"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
    t.integer  "operation_id"
    t.string   "type"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  create_table "distributions_models", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "distribution_id"
    t.integer "model_id"
  end

  create_table "distributions_operations", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "distribution_id"
    t.integer "operation_id"
  end

  create_table "models", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "operations", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "operator"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
  end

  create_table "sqlite_sp_functions", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.text "name"
    t.text "text"
  end

# Could not dump table "sqlite_stat1" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type '' for column 'tbl'

# Could not dump table "sqlite_stat3" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type '' for column 'tbl'

  create_table "sqlite_vs_links_names", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.text "name"
    t.text "alias"
  end

  create_table "sqlite_vs_properties", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.text "parentType"
    t.text "parentName"
    t.text "propertyName"
    t.text "propertyValue"
  end

  create_table "sqlite_vsp_diagrams", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.text "name"
    t.text "diadata"
    t.text "comment"
    t.text "preview"
  end

end
```

Any help or information would be much appreciated.  I've search these errors online for quite a while, but have found very little online.

Comment: Maybe [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434002/how-to-solve-ruby-installation-is-missing-psych-error) will help?

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to delete schema.rb, which is the schema definition file.

(The first paragraph of comments within this file recommends deleting it and generating a new one, rather than editing it.)

Then just run `rake db:migrate`, which performs all the migrations and re-creates the schema.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

I got the similar error either and I have no idea. But when I delete those code, in this case,

**try delete these line:**

```
create_table "sqlite_sp_functions", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.text "name"
  t.text "text"
end

# Could not dump table "sqlite_stat1" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type '' for column 'tbl'

# Could not dump table "sqlite_stat3" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type '' for column 'tbl'

create_table "sqlite_vs_links_names", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.text "name"
  t.text "alias"
end

create_table "sqlite_vs_properties", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.text "parentType"
  t.text "parentName"
  t.text "propertyName"
  t.text "propertyValue"
end

create_table "sqlite_vsp_diagrams", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
  t.text "name"
  t.text "diadata"
  t.text "comment"
  t.text "preview"
end
```

then `rake test:prepare` might work.

Comment: That's only a workaround, though, not a fix, because those lines are regenerated every time another migration is done. This is driving me crazy too, so I wish somebody could identify a proper fix :(

(The same goes for jkdev's answer - delete the schema.rb file and it's regenerated on the next migration).

Comment: @digitig in my case, those lines didn't get regenerated when another migration is done. weird...

Answer (score 0):

Add the following config line to `config/application.rb` or in `config/environments/development.rb`:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.ignore_tables = /^sqlite_*/
```

This will ignore all tables starting with "sqlite_" in your database during the schema dump.