# What is the purpose of sqlite_sp_functions in Rails schema.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Like [some others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741820/sqlexception-on-dbtestload-with-rails), I am having trouble with an error

> "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: object name
>   reserved for internal use: sqlite_sp_functions: CREATE TABLE
>   "sqlite_sp_functions" ("name" text, "text" text)"

when running `rake test` on a Rails project.

The offending lines in `schema.rb` are:

```
create_table "sqlite_sp_functions", id: false, force: true do |t|
  t.text "name"
  t.text "text"
end
```

The suggestions on the previous query about this involved editing `schema.rb` or deleting that file & regenerating it, but `schema.rb` (and the offending code) are regenerated on each migration (plus, I don't want to delete Rails-generated code without knowing the implications), so that's not really a satisfactory solution.

So what is the `sqlite_sp_functions` table for, and how can I get Rails to generate a `schema.rb` file that doesn't break `rake test` for the project?

Answer (score 1):

as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/25077833/601782:

> Add the following config line to `config/application.rb` or in `config/environments/development.rb`:
>
> ```
> ActiveRecord::SchemaDumper.ignore_tables = /^sqlite_*/
> ```
>
> This will ignore all tables starting with "sqlite_" in your database during the schema dump.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the offending lines from your `schema.rb` and then issue:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset
```

which will **completely nuke** your testing database but you shouldn't care anyway. You are not supposed to run migrations for test environments. Migrations are meant to be small (reversible) steps for environments that hold data (such as production and sometimes staging/dev).

The preferred way to handle your testing DB is to use `db:schema:load` as part of your testing routine which will of course delete all your DB data.

Again: Please do not try this in development mode (if you have data that you set up manually) and definitely **not in production**.

Other than that, you could probably delete the whole `sqlite_sp_functions` table from your SQLite testing DB and get rid of the issue altogether. I don't think that this has anything to do with Rails (nor is Rails generating that). I believe that SQLite created this table and your schema just picks it up (as it should). Apparently the table is used to hold stored procedures of some kind.

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset` gives me 'unknown command "RAILS_ENV".

I am not (consciously) running migrations for my test environment, I'm running them for my development environment, but there's only one `schema.db`, automatically generated when I run `rake db:migrate` (on migrations generated by `rails generate scaffold`), and `rake test` (on the tests automatically created when I generated the scaffold) objects to it. I've not touched the way the tests load their data (they're picking it up just fine from automatically generated fixtures).

Comment: are you on windows? if so try `set RAILS_ENV=test` and then issuing `rake db:reset`. Don't forget to set back the environment once you're done.

Comment: That started to run my seed files, which seemed wrong (and which would take about an hour), so I killed it. Should the seed files run in the test environment?

Anyway, I've examined the test.sqlite3 database directly, and there only tables are the one's I specified (and they contain the fixture data from the last test I ran), so is a database reset likely to do anything?

Comment: Well if you are using seed files chances are that you need them during testing as well. If you want to skip the seeding phase `rake db:schema:load` (if you need first `rake db:drop` and `rake db:create`)

Comment: Ok, at least doing the `rake db:drop` as a separate action confirmed that it was the test database that was being affected. Unfortunately, going through that process -- deleting the offending lines, executing `set RAILS_ENV=test`, `rake db:drop` `rake db:create` and `rake db:schema:load` did no good at all. On the next migration, Rake/Rails regenerated `schema.rb` with the offending lines back in.

I don't need the seeds for the test cases, by the way -- everything they need is in the YAML test fixtures.

Comment: Depends on why and how you use `seeds.rb` I guess. So, if you browse your SQLite databases (test and/or production) you see no `sqlite_sp_functions` table?