# Rails: Psych, Updating libyaml from 0.1.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, libyaml

I needed capybara-webkit installed which needed the qt libraries, so I went and installed them using homebrew with the following commands

```
brew update
brew install qt
brew linkapps
```

I then bundled and all was well with the capybara-webkit. However, my guard is throwing the below warning.

```
 You appear to have an outdated version of libyaml (0.1.4) installed on your system.

  Prior to 0.1.6, libyaml is vulnerable to a heap overflow exploit from malicious YAML payloads.


  The easiest thing to do right now is probably to update Psych to the latest version and enable
  the 'bundled-libyaml' option, which will install a vendored libyaml with the vulnerability patched:

  gem install psych -- --enable-bundled-libyaml
```

Seemed simple enough. However, even after a successful psych installation with the 'bundled-libyaml' option I am still seeing this warning about outdated libyaml. Further, when I check the version of libyaml associated with psyche (ruby -rpsych -e 'p Psych.libyaml_version') it's still 1.4.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to:

```
brew upgrade libyaml
```

works for me.

Comment: Be sure to execute 'brew update' to get access to the latest version of libyaml

Answer (score 0):

```
brew update libyaml
```

didn't work for me, but

```
rvm get stable
```

did.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu this worked for me. It reinstalls all rubies so may take a while.

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
rvm reinstall all --force
```

Sample run

```
rvm pkg install libyaml

Beware, 'rvm pkg ...' is deprecated, read about the new autolibs feature: 'rvm help   autolibs'.

Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Fetching yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz to /home/assay/.rvm/archives
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  491k  100  491k    0     0   142k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--  481k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
Extracting yaml to /home/assay/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.6...
Prepare yaml in /home/assay/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.6..
Configuring yaml in /home/assay/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.6..........
Compiling yaml in /home/assay/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.6...................
Installing yaml to /home/assay/.rvm/usr.......

Please note that it's required to reinstall all rubies:

    rvm reinstall all --force
```