# How to update libyaml on Mac OS X for Ruby 2 installed via RVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rvm, libyaml

Lately I started getting the following warning:

```
SafeYAML Warning
----------------

You appear to have an outdated version of libyaml (0.1.4) installed on your system.

Prior to 0.1.6, libyaml is vulnerable to a heap overflow exploit from malicious YAML payloads.

For more info, see:
https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/03/29/heap-overflow-in-yaml-uri-escape-parsing-cve-2014-2525/

The easiest thing to do right now is probably to update Psych to the latest version and enable
the 'bundled-libyaml' option, which will install a vendored libyaml with the vulnerability patched:

gem install psych -- --enable-bundled-libyaml
```

I am on Mac OS X, running `ruby 2.0.0p451` installed via **RVM**.

I've tried the following to no avail:

`brew upgrade libyaml` as per [SO/22919990](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22919990/rails-psych-updating-libyaml-from-0-1-4)

`rvm pkg install libyaml` followed by `rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p451` - [SO/9434002](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434002/how-to-solve-ruby-installation-is-missing-psych-error)

`rvm pkg install libyaml` followed by `rvm reinstall ruby-2.0.0-p451 --with-libyaml-dir=~/.rvm/usr` - [SO/12882190](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882190/unable-to-resolve-ruby-error-missing-psych)

Comment: Have you tried what the error message suggests? `gem install psych -- --enable-bundled-libyaml`

Comment: Oops, yes, I did. That's the first thing I tried. But I haven't tried it again since trying the other three approaches.

Comment: I recently updated `rails_admin` from version `0.6.1` to `0.6.2`, and it in turn updated `safe_yaml ` from version `1.0.2` to `1.0.3` (which was released `April 22, 2014` - i.e. before I had asked this question), and this resolved the issue for me. I should turn my git repo back to before this `rails_admin` update, and see if updating `safe_yaml` alone would do the trick.