# `jekyll serve` causing Load errors in console. Unable to start jekyll server locally

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to run a locally Jekyll server to check my side but after the run: `jekyll serve` command, I get:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/yaml.rb:5:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require': incompatible library version - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/psych-2.2.2/lib/psych.bundle (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/psych-2.2.2/lib/psych.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/yaml.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:120:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/safe_yaml-1.0.4/lib/safe_yaml/load.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/lib/jekyll.rb:29:in `<top (required)>'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in `require'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/jekyll-3.5.2/exe/jekyll:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:26:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:26:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first if you can install `libyaml`:

- [on MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23828248/6309)
- [or on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13630110/6309)

Then `gem install psych`

Check out also [rbenv/ruby-build issue 1251](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1251#issuecomment-446671535) and the `GEM_HOME` setting.