# (Mac Terminal) "System" message when trying to install latest ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rvm

I'm a total newbie when it comes to using Terminal, so I don't really understand what's happening here when I try to upgrade my ruby version (1.8.7) with rvm on a Mac OS X 10.7.3.

When I input

```
rvm install current && rvm use current
```

I get this

```
system
system
```

What does this mean? And how can I proceed with the installation of the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `current` rvm command outputs the name of the currently active installation of Ruby; in this case, it's using your system's pre-installed Ruby (1.8.7).

Try this:

```
rvm install 2.0 # (or whatever version you need)
rvm use 2.0 --default # this sets the default to the 2.0 install
```

Comment: Thanks! I was using the code given in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14182172 but it seems that I did something wrong.

Comment: @pablomaronas - I just upvoted Zach's answer, if it answered your question, you could accept it?