# Installing a gem on Mac OSX with new Ruby Version

Tags: macos, rbenv

I have Mac OSX with Ruby default 1.8.* installed.

I would like to install the following gem:
https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/WWDC-Downloader

When initialling trying to install this I got an error:
Error installing wwdcdownloader:
    nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.

I then looked around and found this SO question about using rbenv. [How to update Ruby to 1.9.x on Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696564/how-to-update-ruby-to-1-9-x-on-mac)

I have now installed rbenv - https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/ also installed ruby-1.9.3-p327

However, when I try to install the gem wwdc (from top) I get an error:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.

So how do I tell terminal to install using this latest ruby version?

EDIT ----- 
The gem installation is now complete
Successfully installed wwdcdownloader-20.13.5
14 gems installed

However, when I run the next command in terminal from here ( https://github.com/jfahrenkrug/WWDC-Downloader)
I get another error:
-bash: wwdcdownloader: command not found??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't told rbenv you want to use the new ruby, with either

```
rbenv global {version}
```

or

```
rbenv local {version}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know nearly nothing about ruby, so could you explain what changing the global/local does and any implications please?