# Cannot install Alamofire in new Xcode Project. "No Such module Alamofire"

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking, alamofire

I follow the instructions to the T. Fresh install of all, yet getting the error:

"No Such module Alamofire"

Directions here:

> In the meantime, you can simply add Alamofire as a git submodule, drag the Alamofire.xcodeproj file into your Xcode project, and add the framework product as a dependency for your application target.

And my screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to add the lib to 'the Link Binary With Libraries' section also

Comment: Yep. Thanks.  What i noticed was that if i had it still set to device, it gave me a bug, but when i went back to simulator worked! Then went back to device, and no error. Enjoy your bounty. :-)

Comment: Thanks:-) I have just posted an answer, with slightly more information. Happy coding.

Comment: Same problem using cocoapods...

Comment: shows you what a garbage dev setup xcode is, that you need to post screenshots in the question.

Comment: The instruction at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40360050/1804274 solved my issue successfully

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Make sure you haven't added any files from Alamofire to your project except for the Alamofire.xcodeproj

Here is step by step instruction:

1. Download and unarchive Alamofire
2. Copy the root folder of Alamofire to any subfolder of your project. Libs, for example.
3. Drag and drop Alamofire.xcodeproj to your Xcode project
4. Open project settings of your project, Build Phases pane, expand Target Dependencies section, and add Alamofire as new dependency
5. Open General pane, expand Embedded Binaries section, and add Alamofire.framework
6. **`import Alamofire`** // in your source file
7. **`Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")`** // use Alamofire

Comment: The [README for the project](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) is updated now with different steps. Linking here so people have the most up-to-date version.

Comment: These directions (along with READ ME) are confusing for newbs. For example, step 2 copy the folder in finder or in xcode? 3. Where should you drop AF.xcodeproj? 4 Alamofire doesn't come up, what now? 5, 6, 7 just don't work because the the other steps failed.

Comment: So none of the answers here worked for me, I've gone over this again and again, but I still get "No such module".

Project has been added under my project, deployment target is the same (8.1) for both, under my build target for the main project I've added Alamofire under Target Dependencies, Link Binary With Libraries and I've added the Copy Frameworks step, set Destination to Frameworks and added the Alamofire.framework in there.

Cleared build dir, removed derived data dir, and yet when I try to do "import Alamofire" I get told there is no such module.

Edit: And I've tried restarting xcode.

Comment: I still cant get any of this to work. Ive followed multiple different variations of these instructions and I still get the No such module, Is it normal to see the framework names appear in RED when adding them to Link binary area. Mine always show as red text

Comment: Not working after updating Xcode to 6.3. The project was working fine before

Comment: What about instructions for CocoaPods?

Comment: thanks i was try it from last three days. you save my [Time=$$$]

Answer (score 13):

You need to add the lib to '`the Link Binary With Libraries`' section also.

The `target Dependencies` makes sure your lib is (re)-build before your target (useful when you makes changes to the lib) and the Link section makes sure the lib is available doing the link phase.

**EDIT**
The above description works for most projects. However alarmofire just updated the process needed for this particular project here https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: I just recently committed to the Alamofire project and we changed the repo to state that you should add the library to the "Target Dependencies" section and not the "Link with Binary" section. [Here is the issue](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/53) with the details.

Answer (score 11):

Banged my head against this for a couple days and figured I would throw this in here, our team project had this issue when bringing Alamofire in as a submodule. If you have your own scheme configurations, you need to duplicate them in the Alamofire.xcodeproj too. Which also likely means you need to fork Alamofire to keep these changes synced up.

Comment: This just happened to me as well. Didn't resolve until I had same configuration in Alamofire as in my app target

Comment: This was my issue with a different framework but similar integration! Man why can't apple have an error message like "No configuration "abcde" found".

Answer (score 5):

This order of the Build Phases has worked for me.

- Target Dependencies
- Link Binary With Libraries.
- Check Pods Manifest.lock
- Embed Pods Frameworks
- Compile Sources

You can rearrange Build Phases by dragging them.

Answer (score 4):

After following [NAlexN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire/25872859#25872859) steps, it still didn't work for me
I also had to change the order of Build Phases.

It was
  - Target Dependencies
  - Compile Sources
  - Link Binary With Libraries.

After I modified to:
  - Target Dependencies
  - Link Binary With Libraries.
  - Compile Sources

It built and ran fine!

Answer (score 2):

I resolved the error "No such module" for a fresh project, not for Alamofire but for another library called "RATreeView"

I had to add

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' 
use_frameworks!
pod "RATreeView", "~> 2.1.0"
```

to the Podfile
and ran

```
pod update
```

The key is to add use_frameworks! It might help someone

Answer (score 1):

Similar errors when I used cocoapods..

I solved the problem by the following steps:

1. Update to Ruby 2.2.0+. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14182172/1453505)
2. Update cocoapods 0.36.0+ (`sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`)
3. Again `pod install`

Answer (score 1):

- Open your project's .workspace file
- Open "Manage Schemes" of your project in Xcode
- Select "Alamofire" in scheme list
- Clean your project

Comment: Spend more than half day looking for an answer, and you save my day. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: Including "Pods.framework" in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" of your target if it not there already. (This applies in case you are are using cocoapods and are using frameworks as modules)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue,doing that Command+B (Build project) and disappear error.

Answer (score -1):

Go to your project folder to be sure you are opening the `.xcworkspace` instead of the `.xcodeproj` file