# "No such module 'Alamofire'" won't recognize framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire

I am trying to add Alamofire to a new XCode project with Swift. I feel like I have tried everything.

Every time I try to add

import Alamofire

I get "No such module".

I have tried installing it as stated on https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire,
I tried doing it manually first, then Carthage and Cocoapods, but with the same result.

I have tried deleting the DerivedData folder and rebuilding the project without any luck.

It is a completely clean install, yet it just won't recognize the framework. I have tried the suggestions in the first 10 Google searches and here on Stackoverflow ([Cannot install Alamofire in new Xcode Project. "No Such module Alamofire"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire)) Here are some screenshots from my latest manual attemp:

[image: General tap]

[image: Dependencies]

Comment: Is Alamofire being built as a module? If not, you'll need to include your framework's header in a bridging header.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have downloaded it through:

git submodule add https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git

to the directory of my project. Do I still need to make a bridging header? I haven't found anywhere, they have mentioned that, but you might be on to something...

Comment: As the project itself has Swift in it (I didn't know it did), you shouldn't need a bridging header. Does the "No Such Module" error happen when you are writing code or when you are building it? Have you tried removing the embed and link binary options and added them back in?

Comment: It happens when I try to build the project after using the import Alamofire statement in one of my files. It can build the project, when I haven't tried to import anything.

Comment: I had the same issue the solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/40360050/1804274 solved my problem successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's late answer, but I was facing same problem with Xcode 8 Swift 3.0. I follow [this Alamofire link](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#installation) and added framework manually. Its working fine. One of my project stuck on 'no such module' error, I cleaned derived data (Cleaning derived data removed source files of Alamofire. I added it again in my project ;) ) and it works like charm :).

Followed instructions

1. Download [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)
2. Drag Alamofire project in your project directory
3. Check alamofire deployment target same as your project
4. Go to your project general settings, click on the + button under the "Embedded Binaries" section.
5. You will see two different Alamofire.xcodeproj folders each with two different versions of the Alamofire.framework nested inside a Products folder. It does not matter which Products folder you choose from, but it does matter whether you choose the top or bottom Alamofire.framework.
6. Select the top Alamofire.framework for iOS and the bottom one for OS X.
7. And that's it! The Alamofire.framework is automagically added as a target dependency, linked framework and embedded framework in a copy files build phase which is all you need to build on the simulator and a device.

Comment: What does that mean ? Check alamofire deployment target same as your project

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you are using the module by directly dropping the source files into your project.

If that's the case, you don't have to use `import Alamofire` header or use `Alamofire( dot )` in the beginning of every method.

Just use the code as below omitting `Alamofire` tag.

```
request(.GET, "https://httpbin.org/get")
```

Comment: That was not the case. I didn't try to use them directly but with the instructions. I can get the whole thing to work by simply dragging all the files of the framework into my project, and then I don't need to import... I guess I have to deal with it like this, when importing it as a framework won't work.

Answer (score 2):

same error here.

I solved the problem by the following steps:

1. Click on your project (targets)
2. Click on `Build Settings`
3. Under `Search Paths`-`Framework Search Paths`, add the directory path which contains Alamofire.framework

Hope this can solve your problem!

Comment: This worked for me. Also, I thought my Framework Search Paths was already set up correctly, but I added another framework that was nested in the path I specified, so I had to change it to be recursive instead of non-recursive.

Answer (score 0):

I was importing Alamofire and I ran into the same issue. Turns out the Cartfile was **not** in the same folder as the **.xcodeproj file**.

Once I moved the *Cartfile*, the *Cartfile.resolved* files and the *Carthage* folder to the same folder as the *.xcodeproj* file my project didn't trigger any errors.

Make sure to also add this line to **Build Settings > Framework Search Paths**:

> $(PROJECT_DIR)/Carthage/Build/iOS

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this issue changing my Podfile. I originally had the reference to Alamofire in a target:

The problem disappeared when I changed the podfile to the following:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'

target 'xxxxxxx' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end

target 'xxxxxxxTests' do
    pod 'GoogleMaps'
end
```