# Cannot add Alamofire to Swift Project

Tags: swift, alamofire

Trying to add alamofire to swift project using unstruction from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25872859/5164739)

Did all these steps, clean project a lot of timer and restarted XCode, nothing helps. Error does not dissappear

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNU3R.png

"Cannot load underlying module for 'Alamofire'" and nothing to do

Changes I did:

1) added project file to my project

i.stack.imgur.com/eUe8E.png

2) added to build phases panel

i.stack.imgur.com/1wanl.png

3) added to general tab

i.stack.imgur.com/L3TTR.png

What`s wrong with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I was able to fix it by doing the following.

1. Download the Alamofire "Source" folder.
   https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/master/Source
2. Drag it into your xCode Project, and click "Copy Items if Needed". If you view the project in Finder, the Alamofire Source folder should be in the project itself. (Ex: I have 3 items. Example App, Example App.xcodeproj, Example App Tests. The folder should be in Example App.)
3. Finally, you should be done! However, now, you do not need to import Alamofire, since you are not actually loading a framework.
   For example, instead of doing Alamofire.upload, you will now only do upload.

Comment: Thanks man :) I`ve just updated my question field with steps I did with your advices

Comment: @swiftstudier If the answer helped you, accept it and upvote it too

Comment: I dont know for what you comment, I did it after fixing my question

Comment: But I am getting error even if i don't import. Please let me know what has to be done to compile the library?

Comment: @Thilak Please upload a screenshot.

Comment: Yh @dannybess this didnt work for me either, but since it worked for others, could anyone please share how to use it, when you are done including it in your project. Cos step 3 doesn't seem to work for me.