# How to send data to the server(api) using swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, swift2

Hi all am developing a app using swift2 am having api key in Json format i can able to work with that and it provides some data such as success:1,error:0 if i get the value success 1 means i want to send the entered data or saved data to a server(api key).How to do that??

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you know about afnetwoking ?

Comment: NO dude....can you refer something??

Comment: @antonyraja I dont even know why you think more pods = more battery consumtion...really man? I think you should learn the basic of coding first before trying to dev anything, else it wont work well and possibly of many bugs

Comment: in my app am updating current location for every 1 minutes even app in background active...so already it consumes more memory thats the reason i dont want to add any additional frameworks and pods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can send data to server by using Alamofire API. It's documention and implemention all the stuff are mentioned in the following link.

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Just install it using Pods and it's very easy to implement.

create Network Class and create following function inside it.

```
   func get_Request(currentView : UIViewController,action : NSString,completionHandler: (NSDictionary -> Void)) {
    print("Url==>>>",mainURl + (action as String))

    Alamofire.request(.GET,mainURl + (action as String), parameters: nil)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let JSON = response.result.value {
                completionHandler(JSON as! NSDictionary)
            }
            else{
                printf(response.result.error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
}
```

Other class

```
viewDidLoad{
    NetworkClass.get_Request(self,action: "yourServiceName/" + (yourParameters as String), completionHandler: self.resultHandler)
}
func resultHandler(result : NSDictionary) -> Void {

    printf("result is -->>",result)

}
```

Comment: I dont want to use cocoapod because am already using two pods..if i again add the cocoapod means my app will drain battery...so is there any other way to do????

Comment: @antonyraja:  Who said using more than one cocoapod will drain battery?

Comment: Pods are just store files from source to your project instead you manually import them.Pods does not affect your battery consumptions.

Comment: Pods are best way rather then manually .Because when any update come's in the library then you need to remove old files and add new file into project but using pods you can easily update them.

Comment: but if you want to do it then just follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706589/how-to-add-alamofire-to-xcode-project-swift

Comment: using this alomofire how to send the data

Comment: Have u Read the alamofire documention in the link of gitHub i mentions.you can get solution how to send data. Try it once otherwise i give you the solution

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '3.2.1'

Comment: i have updated my pods(Alamofire)....now am getting a value in textfield...i want to send that data to server(i.e...api)...how to send???? @SumitDhariwal

Comment: i have updated my pods(Alamofire)....now am getting a value in textfield...i want to send that data to server(i.e...api)...how to send???? @SumitDhariwal

Comment: it helps to print the parameter and fetch result as SUCCESS or FAILURE but i dont know where to work with this coding that is public enum Result<Value, Error: ErrorType> { case success(value) case failure(Error)}

Comment: Because am implementing in button action

Comment: am having two text field change password and confirm change password and am having one button action...inside that action i have to perform but your updated answer is confusing where to use it..can you explain little bit more????

Comment: don't be confuse ,you just need to create a singleton Network class and a function which use to call api's ,in button action you just call api method of network class and pass your parameters,action,current View so that you can show indicator on current view and also a completion handler which can receive the result after successfull hit of api.

Comment: am not comfortable with ios development man....can you refer any example or stackoverflow answers regarding my solution....thank you..@SumitDhariwal