# Alamofire 2.0 Swift No Type name Request in module Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I updated the alamofire to 2.0 , 
but I'm having the following problem when a build

"No type named 'Request' in module 'Alamofire'

[image]

someone can help me,

thanks

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire

Comment: And if you are doing correctly, just restart Xcode, it might be bad luck today.

Comment: When in doubt, clean the project first

Comment: thanks, but this still giving error