# iOS: "no such module" with Alamofire

Tags: ios, distribution, xcode7, alamofire

I have this error when I try to archive my app (adHoc or distribution)

**"NO SUCH MODULE"**

[image]

I followed all the instructions in the official page

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#manually (manually installation)

But when I **RUN** my app it works fine, and when I try to **ARCHIVE** it to get ipa for distribution or adHoc version, I get the error in the image above.

What happen?

p.s. I use xCode 7.0.1 with swift 2.0

Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using Xcode beta? Which branch of Alamofire are you using?

Comment: I'm sorry I left a zero :-) Xcode 7.0.1,

Comment: @Logan the original question said 7.1 not 7.0.1.

Comment: any reason why you're not using Cococapods?

Comment: I don't like Cocoapods... the branch is "master"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install Alamofire in new Xcode Project. "No Such module Alamofire"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire)

Comment: I just read that thread... no solution for me...

Comment: @nazz_areno -- first up all sorry senior, this cause will occur many scenarios, we won't give the exact answer that is the reason , i add  the Link

Comment: I told u because my problem is different, there happen in normal debug situation, for me is during the archiving

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange issue being seen with Xcode 7.0.1, Swift 2.0. Even I am seeing the same issue here. Current workaround is to include the Alamofire sources directly into your project and remove the framework.

Once you add the Alamofire sources, you need to remove the 'Alamofire' module prefix to successfully build the project.

Note: None of the solutions mentioned in 
[Cannot install Alamofire in new Xcode Project. "No Such module Alamofire"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire)

are working for me at the moment!.

This seems to be an issue with Xcode 7.0.1 than Alamofire.

Comment: Hmm, @nazz_areno, that is a static lib, so it works, no embedding of it right?