# Cannot distribute inhouse build with ios-charts library embedded to my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios-charts

first of all, I would like to thank you for creating this library. I have embedded it in my project (as written in the README file) by dragging it into the project, embedding it in the binaries and so on. Target iOS version is 8.0.

Everything worked great for dev version of the app, but as soon as I built the inhouse version, app crashes after initial welcome screen shows. Logs for the crash are as following:

```
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Error>:  SecTrustEvaluate  [leaf IssuerCommonName SubjectCommonName]
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: xpcproxy[700] Container: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6D451583-EE0E-4F0A-9CA9-2E33F83D6138 (sandbox)
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone kernel[0] <Notice>: AMFI: energy_challenge(pid 700) - [deny-mmap] mapped executable file has no team identifier in its signature: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/84AEA7F2-4987-4119-B3CC-A4EAFC9989DC/energy_challenge.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework/Charts
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.edge5.nativeMenuEnergieInhouse[0x1f2e][700]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone assertiond[63] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 700: (os/kern) failure (5)
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: Unable to register for exec notifications: No such process
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 700: (os/kern) failure (5)
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for <FBApplicationProcess: 0x13226dc00; com.edge5.nativeMenuEnergieInhouse; pid: 700>
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.edge5.nativeMenuEnergieInhouse[0x1f2e]' crashed.
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone SpringBoard[54] <Warning>: Application '(null)' exited for an unknown reason.
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone ReportCrash[701] <Notice>: Formulating report for corpse[700] energy_challenge
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone ReportCrash[701] <Warning>: report not saved because the limit of 25 for 109_energy_challenge logs has been reached.
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone ReportCrash[701] <Error>: Notice: This report is abbreviated for syslog inclusion because it could not be saved to disk.
    Symbolication may be possible by manually cleaning up and including the Binary Image section of a full report from this same device -- good luck!
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone ReportCrash[701] <Error>: Process:             energy_challenge [700]
    Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/84AEA7F2-4987-4119-B3CC-A4EAFC9989DC/energy_challenge.app/energy_challenge
    OS Version:          iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone ReportCrash[701] <Error>: Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000120095088
    Triggered by Thread:  0
Oct 20 15:54:15 iPhone ReportCrash[701] <Error>: Dyld Error Message:
    Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/Charts.framework/Charts
      Referenced from: /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/84AEA7F2-4987-4119-B3CC-A4EAFC9989DC/energy_challenge.app/energy_challenge
      Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/84AEA7F2-4987-4119-B3CC-A4EAFC9989DC/energy_challenge.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework/Charts: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/84AEA7F2-4987-4119-B3CC-A4EAFC9989DC/energy_challenge.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework/Charts'
      Dyld Version: 369.12
Oct 20 15:54:16 iPhone wifid[39] <Error>: WiFi:[467042056.241745]: Enable WoW requested by "apsd"
Oct 20 15:54:16 iPhone wifid[39] <Error>: WiFi:[467042056.243839]: Unable to dispatch WowStateChanged message to client dataaccessd (268435460)
Oct 20 15:54:16 iPhone wifid[39] <Error>: WiFi:[467042056.244041]: Unable to dispatch WowStateChanged message to client MobileMail (268435460)
Oct 20 15:54:16 iPhone wifid[39] <Error>: WiFi:[467042056.244185]: Unable to dispatch WowStateChanged message to client softwareupdatese (268435460)
Oct 20 15:54:16 iPhone wifid[39] <Error>: WiFi:[467042056.244422]: Unable to dispatch WowStateChanged message to client dataaccessd (268435460)
Oct 20 15:54:16 iPhone wifid[39] <Error>: WiFi:[467042056.244678]: Unable to dispatch WowStateChanged message to client assistantd (268435460)
Oct 20 15:54:16 iPhone wifid[39] <Error>: WiFi:[467042056.245010]: Unable to dispatch WowStateChanged message to client itunesstored (268435460)
```

The problem occurs here:

```
[deny-mmap] mapped executable file has no team identifier in its signature: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/84AEA7F2-4987-4119-B3CC-A4EAFC9989DC/energy_challenge.app/Frameworks/Charts.framework/Charts
```

I tried creating new certificate, new inhouse build, basically went through all the stackoverflow questions regarding this or similar issue (eg. https://www.airsignapp.com/ios-apps-using-swift-crash-when-signed-with-inhouse-certificate/) without any success. Is it possible that maybe you need to change something certificate-related on your side?

Thank you very much for any answer

Comment: Is it in Xcode 7.0.1?

Comment: @Shripada yes, it is.

Comment: Had a similar issue :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042068/ios-no-such-module-with-alamofire/33208300?noredirect=1#comment54312176_33208300

Comment: @Wingzero I will give it a try and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post when I was searching for "[deny-mmap] mapped executable file has no team identifier in its signature" on Google.

It turned out that the old Apple WWDR Cert expired on 14 Feb 2016. If your OSX still has that expired cert in Keychain Access, your Distribution Certificate would be regarded as invalid. (A red line showing "This certificate has an invalid issuer") You could forcefully "trust" that cert in Keychain Access, but the side effect is that the signed binary would NOT have TeamIdentifier in its signature:

```
$ codesign -d -vv MyApp.app
Executable=/Users/admin/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier=info.eddywong.MyApp
Format=bundle with Mach-O universal (armv7 arm64)
CodeDirectory v=20100 size=1920 flags=0x0(none) hashes=87+5 location=embedded
Signature size=4389
Authority=iPhone Distribution: Eddy Wong Limited (KG7UETNRCJ)
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Signed Time=15 Mar 2016 23:59:38
Info.plist entries=33
TeamIdentifier=not set
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=12 files=108
```

So I had to follow the solution posted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35400712 - to remove the old, expired WWDR certificate in "System" keychain.

Then, I cleaned and re-archive, then export IPA. This time it works!

The reason why "Everything worked great for dev version of the app" is that dev version of the app is signed by your own developer cert, not your organization's distribution cert. I can't figure out why developer cert is not affected by WWDR expiry, though. But I could verify that the dev signed binary does have the TeamIdentifier set, while the dist signed binary doesn't.