# "No such module 'Alamofire'" Xcode won't recognize Alamofire framework

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I realize that the same error was asked in other questions (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire)), but their solutions are not working for me.
I keep getting a build failure in my app: "No such module 'Alamofire'". I followed the cocoadocs installation instructions ([here](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Alamofire/3.3.0/)) for installing Alamofire and it still is not working. I made sure everything has the same deployment target.
[Embedded Binaries and Frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DhwR.png)

Here's my podfile text.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, ‘9.2’
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.0'
end

target 'MyAppTests' do

end

target 'MyAppUITests' do

end
```

Also, I tried "$ pod install" again in Terminal and got this message:

```
[!] The `App [Debug]` target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

After following Sohil's suggestions, XCode now recognizes the Alamofire module, but 22 new issues have arisen.

[image: New Errors]

Update #2: So I'm now on Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2, but I'm receiving a new error with the workspace Link: "ld: framework not found Alamofire. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)."

Comment: Make sure you load the xcworkspace rather than the project

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do the following things and you can import any swift file from "Pods"

> 1) Clean your project
>
> 2) Make sure that all your "Pods" > "Build Settings" > "Build Active
>   Architecture Only" is set to "NO".
>
> 3) Don't run, just build your project.
>
> 4) Now, import any file from "Pods" to any swift file
>
> E.g.: import Alamofire
>
> 5) Again, build project and it will work as expected. Finally, you can
>   access it properties

**Update:**

For the updated question, I hope you are using Xcode 7.3 so please update the `Alamofire` to Swift 2.2

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: So I'm now on Xcode 7.3 and Swift 2.2, but I'm receiving a new error with the workspace Link: "ld: framework not found Alamofire. clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)."

Comment: @S.Sohi Please post the screenshot

Comment: I opened a new project, transferred my files, trashed the old project, and then installed Cocoapods and Alamofire again. Now everything is working with no errors.

Comment: @SohilR.Memon when you say `import`what do you exactly mean?

Comment: @Julián `import` module of any Pods

Comment: @S.Sohi thats exactly the only solution that worked for me, too! sad, but true. thanks for pointing me to that.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Added some new Pods to my project and this solved my problem of XCode not 'finding' them. Thanks!

Comment: it solved my alamofire problem but showing same error for another pod. I did same for my every pod but not getting any solution.

Answer (score 4):

Please check this screenshot 
and compare to your build setting
may this is helpful to you

[image]

Comment: In my case the pod was in a subfolder, now it works using: "$PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/Pods/Alamofire"

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was to open the "App".xcworkspace as pointed by the [cocoapods documentation](https://cocoapods.org/)

The steps was:

1. Close project
2. Close xcode
3. Go to terminal
4. type "open |App|.xcworkspace"

When I opened Xcode it was still pointing the error then I built the project (cmd+b) and everything is fine now.

Comment: After two days effort I found this solution, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting.

Use the `$(inherited)` flag in TARGENTS -> Build Settings -> Framework Search Paths

Answer (score 0):

in my case, i couldn't run archive after change bundle name. I've cleaned build folder and run pod install then everything worked fine.