# Can Build and Run, But Upon Archiving, Error Appears "No such module 'Alamofire'"

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire, archive

I can run my project with no errors, but cannot archive it for distribution because I get the error "No such module 'Alamofire'"

Are my project settings wrong?

[Project Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srQNW.png)

[Error message produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcMJY.png)

Comment: Clean and try to re-install the pods

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No such module 'Alamofire'" Xcode won't recognize Alamofire framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417151/no-such-module-alamofire-xcode-wont-recognize-alamofire-framework)

Comment: @Benjamin Lowry, it's not a duplicate. That question is about Alamofire not appearing at all. This is about it not appearing upon archiving. It otherwise works on build and run.

Comment: But does cleaning the build folder not work? I've had this problem before, and that's what solved it.

Comment: And it's the same error, just at different times for the record.

Comment: Cleaning doesn't work. Cmd + Shift + K let's me build and run, but not archive.

Answer (score 0):

Try Command + Shift + K to clean your project, and Xcode will search for dependencies again.

Thereafter, build and run again.