# Cocoapods: Cannot load module 'Alamofire' as 'Alamofire'

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

Update: I solved the question. Please see my answer below (underneath the question and comments).

This question was marked as a duplicate, but it's different because it is a brand new error that I couldn't find through any searches.

---

I tried installing Alamofire into my XCode project.

As per their their tutorial, I installed cocoapods onto my system.
I then navigated to the folder of my existing xcode project in the terminal, and did:

`pod init`

I then edited the new pod file and added:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'RainyShinyCloudy' do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
end
```

Finally, I executed the command:

```
pod install
```

My terminal told me the install was successful.

But when I opened the .xcworkspace, made a new swift class and tried to import Alamofire, I got this error:

[image]

One possible reason could be that I had tried to install an earlier version of alamofire earlier, deleted it and then installed this.

But I really don't know how that could have mattered.

Thanks for any help you guys can give me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No such module 'Alamofire'" Xcode won't recognize Alamofire framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417151/no-such-module-alamofire-xcode-wont-recognize-alamofire-framework)

Comment: Please check the above answer. It has already been solved and if's not do comment there!

Comment: I believe my issue is different than the others. Their errors are all in the form of "No such module 'Alamofire' While mine says cannot load 'Alamofire'. It could be similar, but I already tried their solutions they did not work for me.

Comment: Run it, it will detect atrun time..

Comment: When I run it, the build just fails because of the error

Comment: Clean (CMD + SHIFT + K) and just build (CMD + B) - try this out!

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried this along with answers all over stack overflow many times, but they have not worked. I even set Build Active Architectures Only = YES, as was suggested by many answers, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install Alamofire in new Xcode Project. "No Such module Alamofire"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: I posted an answer earlier that was wrong.

But now I actually figured it out.

I made a new project, went to the settings menu by clicking on the name of my app in the project explorer.

Then I went to `Linked frameworks and libraries` which is at the very bottom of the `General` tab.

I pressed that little + icon, selected `Alamofire.framework.` and set the status to `required`

Following this, cleaning and rebuilding the project made the error go away.

Answer (score 3):

Actually it failed because you were trying to import `AlamoFire` and not `Alamofire`. Imports are case sensitive.