# Why did my pod imports suddenly stop working?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, alamofire

I use several `pods` including `AlamoFire`, `Realm` and `SwiftyJSON`. The `pods` and their code worked fine up until recently. Now None of my imports work, but gives me the error `No such Module`.

I have tried to use the command `pod disintegrate` in the terminal, then installed them again. I have linked them to the project in the `general` tab as well as the `project phase` tab.

I have tried following the steps here:

["No such module 'Alamofire'" Xcode won't recognize Alamofire framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417151/no-such-module-alamofire-xcode-wont-recognize-alamofire-framework)

But step two doesn't seem to exist in the `build settings` and if I comment out all the imports I instead get another error:

`The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.`

I use swift 4.1 which is verified in the `build settings`. I use Xcode 9.4.1 if that helps.

Very confused about this problem since everything worked fine until it suddenly stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your podfile if you have mentioned explicitly version for one of the dependency 
For e.g
Alamofire, ~>’3.3’

Check for the compatible version for swift 4.1 if you have mentioned explicitly version for one of the pod.

Otherwise Simply remove podfile.lock  and try pod update once.

---

The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.

- Select the target which uses swift
- Go to Build Settings
- Type Swift L in search field and scroll to Swift Language Version
- Select the language version

Comment: That last part about the `Swift Language Version` fixed the whole thing. The trick was to check the `language version` for ALL pods. Previously I only checked it for the project itself. Turns out `SwiftyJSON` was set to version 5. Changing it to 4.1 fixed everything. Thanks alot for your assistance @Abhi