# " No such module 'Alamofire' " when im using TodayExtension target to my viewcontroller which i have to access in TodayViewController

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!


target 'currentProject' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

 pod 'Alamofire', '4.0'
  # Pods for currentProject

end
target 'todayViewController' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for todayViewController

end
```

i written the podfile as shown as above . i have to access one of my view controller form my project in my todayextension .so i added my todayExtension to the target.
at that time it showing the error " No such module 'Alamofire' "

Comment: Make sure you are opening .xcworkspace, not .xcodeproj

Comment: yes im opening the workspace actually the problem is a class which used a library inside it cant use in my todayExtension . which causes the library in the class showing "No Such Module" @KishanBhatiya

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36417151/no-such-module-alamofire-xcode-wont-recognize-alamofire-framework

Comment: I vaguely remember encountering a similar problem. At that time, I just deleted `inherit! :search_paths` and put `pod 'Alamofire', '4.0'` in the second block as well. Repetitive, I know, but it somehow works.