# Alamofire is not compatible with swift 2.1.1 and Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Currently i'm using `Alamofire-3.4.1` with `swift 2.1.1` and `Xcode 7.2.1` version. It showing error i.e 'No such module Alamofire'. My OS X Yosemite version is `10.10.5`. Is it compatibility issue or other? Which version of `Alamofire` should i use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot install Alamofire in new Xcode Project. "No Such module Alamofire"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire)

Comment: Alamofire 3.4.1 uses swift 2.2 which is not compatible with older Xcode's & swift 2.1.
use Xcode 7.3 or Alamofire 3.2.x.

Comment: Thanx for Reply @srvv... Alamofire is working with 3.2.x version. :)

Answer (score 1):

Alamofire 3.4.1 uses swift 2.2 which is not compatible with previous versions of swift & Xcode older than v7.3.

Either use Xcode 7.3 
OR 
Alamofire 3.2.x which is the last version supporting swift 2.1.

For future reference, visit Alamofire releases on `github`. It provides detailed release notes with migration notes for any source breaking changes.