# Alamofire framework not found(Xcode-8.2.1 and iOS 10.2)

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods, xcode8, alamofire

[image]I have tried so many solutions out there but finally not getting what to do . I just installed **cocoa pods for Alamofire and swiftyJson** . And now when i **clean and build** my project i get an error

> NO SUCH FRAMEWORK ALAMOFIRE

when I try import Alamofire in any swift file it says:

> NO SUCH MODULE ALAMOFIRE

My Updated Podfile is something like this( **No such framework Alamofire** error is solved  by this pod file). But still getting No such **Module alamofire**-:

```
  # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, ’10.2’


source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'ModesTests' do
use_frameworks!
 pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'

  target 'ModesUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

This is how I created **Modes.xcworkspace** and installed **pods and created pod file** -:

1) Open Terminal

2) Navigate to the directory containing your ModesSample project by using the cd command:

3) Give the init command

```
pod init
```

4)Open the Podfile using command-:

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

Created pod file is shown above last step is-:

```
5) pod install
```

**What all I have verified-:**

1) I have added Alamofire.framework under path -: Modes->General->Linked Frameworks and Libraries

2) Tried adding Alamofire directory path under-: Build settings->Framework search paths

3) Verified Build Active Architecture Only values it is-:

```
DEBUG:YES
RELEASE:NO
```

Can anyone please help me solve this, I have tried 3 times now. Thanks

Comment: @Sneak okk got your point do you have any idea about issue ?

Comment: I don't know, this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25817479/cannot-install-alamofire-in-new-xcode-project-no-such-module-alamofire , also, please avoid deleting your questions and reposting them to bump them up. Good luck.

Comment: @Sneaks Thanks i will try doing it again.

Comment: @Sneak, have you tried restarting Xcode?

Comment: you can run `pod deintegrate` and `pod install` and see if installing pods again helps you. Also can you check your `Podfile.lock` and tell what version are being used of alamofire. And can you import swiftjson ?

Comment: Also you don't have to add path of frameworks if you're using cocoapods.

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore pod deintegrate in terminal under my project directory?

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore what if i want to Uninstall cocoapods as well and install it again.

Comment: @TusharSharma Yes in your project directory where you hav `Podfile`. `pod deintegrate` uninstalls the pods from your project.

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore will uninstall pods and do it again and get back when i am done.Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I completely did for **ios-10.2 and Xcode -:8.2.1** (This works great)

1) create a project.

2) Go to terminal

3) give command `cd desktop`(if project on desktop)

4) `cd project name`

5) `pod init`(This created pod file in directory)

6) **use this pod fie-:**

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.2'
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
def shared_pods
use_frameworks!
   pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
target 'Modes' do
   # Pods for Modes
   shared_pods
end
target 'ModesTests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for testing
   shared_pods

 end

 target 'ModesUITests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    shared_pods

   end
```

> **MARK-:** I added **use_frameworks** under function **shared_pods** ( That allowed me to use frameworks) don't put it outside it.

7) Save pod file

8) `pod install`

9) Close Terminal and all open projects .

10) Go to project directory and open **Projectname.xcworkspace.**

11) First **Clean and Build**.

12) import Alamofire

13) Bravo use your frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Paste the below text in your podfile.

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'ModesTests' do
 pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'

  target 'ModesUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

save it.
And then run a command "$ pod install" in terminal.(if you had didnt install previously).
if you want to update the Alamofire then run command "$ pod update"

Thank you..!!!

Comment: hi your command was useful but there was one more step to do -: go to Build settings->framework Search Paths -> add this -: `$(inherited)`. Then clean and build.

Comment: I get this warning now -: directory not found for option '-F``' .

Comment: resolved it by only adding $(inherited) to Pods->Build settings->framework Search Paths

Comment: it is not giving any framework not found error but now when I import Alamofire it says no such module.:(

Comment: Just close your project and move to your project path and open the projectName.xcworkspace  file which  get created when you install Pod

Comment: I am opening that only.

Comment: try this. Clean your project by pressing Alt+ shift +k and the write code @import Alamofire; in your project

Comment: added screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Podfile with the following

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.2'
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!


def shared_pods
   pod 'Alamofire'
   pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end
target 'Modes' do
   # Pods for Modes
   shared_pods
end
target 'ModesTests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for testing
   shared_pods

 end

 target 'ModesUITests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
    shared_pods

   end
```

Do the pod deintegrate and pod install again.

Comment: Thanks will try this

Comment: Thanks for your code a little idea by me and we solved it.:)

Answer (score 0):

You need not have to link frameworks (Alamofire or SwiftyJSON) when fetched from pod. All linking is done automatically from pod. You just need to import them.

I tried this for you and it worked.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNRtC.png)

Comment: so what should i link ?? like-: Pods_Modes.framework something?

Comment: nope. I guess you solved it by deintegrating your pods from project. But still you don't have to do any manual linking of pods. You can do "$pod clean" as well to remove existing workspace  and create a fresh.

Comment: nopes pod deintegrate didn't solved it.What actually solved was writing use_framworks under target 'Modes'