# Linker command failed with exit code (No such module)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently being struck on this problem.

As I have updated all the pods, cococapods, Macos, Xcode. I just meet this problem. I have searched for 2 days about the problems online, but nothing worked for me.

I am using XCODE3 , while I was running the project, it shows Linker command failed with exit code 1, while I clicked it, I can't see anything changed, there was no more info on show. 
[image]
and then I tried to run it in terminal with command : xcodebuild -verbose. I could see the reason which is error: no such module 'ObjectMapper'. after I remove the ObjectMapper, it tells me can not find another module. so I think it is the xcode can not link the framework. 
[image]

I have linked all relevant framework to the linked frameworks and libraries but still can not work.
[image]

Can anybody help me with it.Thanks

Here is my pod file :

[image]

Comment: i have tried many options like : removing DerivedData, clean, reopen, re-link and so on. can not work

Comment: what framework are you installing?

Comment: I didn't install any new framework, these are all old framework installed before and i just update all by using pod update.

Comment: can you click on that linker error a new view will open up drag to its end and see what it says.

Comment: I clicked it many many times...... nothing on happened.

Comment: are you opening xcworkspace?You can do pod deintegrate and pod install again.Try to clean and build your project once.

Comment: I tried this as well. not work either. Im opening xcworkspace.

Comment: have you tried pod install again?Can you show your pod file.?

Comment: please see the edited question, Thanks , I tried pod install as well

Comment: I have explained here how to install pods properly you can try my answer here it is answer  to my question only.just specific your pods instead of mine. -: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43245202/alamofire-framework-not-foundxcode-8-2-1-and-ios-10-2

Comment: Are you using xcode8 and swift3?

Comment: im using xcode 8 and swift 3, Im checking your answer, do you have some suggestions about my podfile? Thanks

Comment: you can do pod install manually no need to write that code in pod file.And you are writing use_framework 2 times why is that so? Few targets are also missing.

Comment: You try my pod I bet it will work for you.

Comment: I have added the new pod screenshot, please check it . it still doesn't work

Comment: uncomment that 2nd line specifying platform give your iOS platform like (10.2 I guess)  there. And do pod install again after doing pod deintegrate.Can you also show me your terminal output after pod install.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using swift libraries, set "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" flag in build settings to YES