# How do I change my Ruby version using RVM?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am not able to switch the current Ruby version:

```
➜  ~  rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p0 [ x86_64 ]

➜  ~  rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p0

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

Comment: are you sure you installed rvm correctly ? what OS are you using ?

Comment: Append the output of `rvm info` to your question please.

Comment: I had a similar problem by installing rvm with apt-get on Ubuntu 11.10, I had to remove it and reinstall it with `$ bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer)
`

Comment: Do you have the RVM load function in your shell's startup script? `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` is the code to use. If you have RVM installed in your path, but you don't have that in your startup script, you can get the `RVM is not a function` error.

Comment: This solution works for me - https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Fixed it. I needed to add:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM
```

to `.zshrc`

Answer (score 58):

This happened to me too. I had:

```
export PATH=~/.rvm/bin:$PATH
```

Added in my .bashrc.

All I had to do was add another

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

to the same file and it worked!
Of course, you have to restart your terminal after that.

Comment: i had this same line (the [[ -s "$HOME/...) in my ~/.bash_profile and that didn't seem to "take" when i opened a new terminal...but when i added the line below the PATH line in the ~/.bashrc, it did work -- meaning, i could type rvm use 1.9.3 and it would immediately recognize rvm as a command without me needing to first type source ~/.bash_profile -- i'm not a linux person, so this confuses me, but i'm glad this got it working. perhaps someone can clarify my confusion.

Comment: that's great, i just put this line in ~/.bashrc, it works. but i also don't know why.

Comment: Yeah its working. But every time I restart my machine I have to give above mentioned commands. If I do not provide the commands it says rvm is not a function.

Answer (score 11):

Your shell doesn't know about the RVM function. After you install it, it tells you how to take care of this. Or go to the [install](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) page on the RVM site and check out the section titled "2. Load RVM into your shell sessions as a function"

Run this once to add the line that loads rvm into your ~/.bash_profile:

```
$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

or manually add it yourself. (Note that on some systems, you will want to put it in other places, for example on my system, Mac OSX Lion, I put it in ~/.profile)

Comment: I'm using OS X Snow Leopard, putting that line in my .profile did the trick for me.

Answer (score 9):

(Kubuntu 11.10) The  `~/.bash_profile` is now called `~/.profile`

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.profile
source ~/.profile
rvm info # And now the fields display
```

Answer (score 6):

To Change the Default Version of ruby:

In Ubuntu 11.10 
please change your GNOME terminal setting :

Go to **Terminal** and then follow the following instructions:

```
1.  Edit > Profile Preferences
2.  Open Title and Command Tab               
3.  Check Run Command as a login Shell 
4.  Restart terminal
```

Run this command on terminal:

```
rvm --default use ruby_Version
```

Answer (score 5):

To add all RVM functionality to your .bash_profile you should use following command:

```
echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After that you should reload the current shell or open a new terminal session and type the following command to reload .bash_profile:

```
source .bash_profile
```

Answer (score 4):

The above solution will only work, if RVM is installed for the current user. A more general solution would use the RVM path variable:

```
# The following code loads RVM as user or system install:
[[ -s "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
```

Comment: `rvm_path=/home/myuser/.rvm . /home/myuser/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Answer (score 3):

I just had to invoke source `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 3):

On a clean install of Ubuntu 12.04 I ran into the same issue. The RVM installer creates or appends to a file called ~/.bash_login the necessary bit of code to avoid the original problem:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

However this does not seem to get invoked.  Adding it to ~/.bashrc resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Installing RVM, See here http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rvm/

Comment: Don't use non-authoratative sources for installing RVM. The [RVM installation page](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) specifically says: "Note that that any outside tutorials are NOT supported whether they work or not. Tutorials are great, however we have spent massive amounts of man hours debugging the installation process. Please use the install process(es) from this site only, as this is the only supported installation types and methods."

Answer (score 1):

In my case  on Ubuntu, the entry in ~/.bashrc had:

```
 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && ."$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # BAD
```

instead of:

```
 [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # WORKING
```

Notice the missing space between . and "$HOME.

Also, if this is the problem, you should also be noticing an error on top when you start your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had a global install of RVM, which runs /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh.  However, that script requires the BASH_VERSION or ZSH_VERSION to be set. I was running from crontab, which uses "sh".

I created a wrapper script that uses /bin/bash to source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login
>   shell. Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the
>   command.