# Ruby update 1.8.7 to 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

When I look at the version of Ruby

```
`$ ruby -v`
```

i get

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

but when I want to upgrade Ruby

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3
```

i get

```
Already installed ruby-1.9.3-p194.
```

What's the problem?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ruby version selected by the rvm is depending on which version of rvm you are using.

Try following

```
   rvm use 1.9.3
   ruby -v
```

To find all the installed versions of ruby use following

```
   rvm list
```

Comment: I'm tried, but get a error: RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

Comment: ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663936/how-do-i-change-my-ruby-version-using-rvm

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem.

The version that you told RVM to use is 1.8.7, and you also have a 1.9.3 installed that you could tell RVM to use if you wanted to.