# Ruby installed via rvm, but ruby -v not working

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've installed Ruby via RVM in my virtual machine.

When I run `rvm list` I have Ruby 2.1.1 listed as both current and default. But when I run `ruby -v` my terminal tells me that `ruby` is not installed, and that I can install Ruby via `apt-get`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I remember how rvm works you have to tell him which ruby you want to use, something like `rvm use <ruby-version>`

Comment: Isn't it already in use when rvm list tells me that ruby 2.1.1 is default and current version?

Comment: Yes, it should... I must say I've not been using rvm for years, so I just can suggest you another ruby versions manager, `rbenv`; I find it simpler and less problematic than rvm

Answer (score 0):

You might not be using the `login shell`. That could be the possible reason why you are unable to select `ruby 2.1.1`. Also, you won't have ruby installed in your system (not using RVM), that's why it is telling to install ruby.

Just reopen another terminal and try the below command from terminal and from your project folder to enter in to the log in shell (normally `bash` profile):

```
/bin/bash --login
```

After that, just run

```
rvm use ruby-2.1.1
```

You don't need to run this command every time you take the terminal. But, for that please refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239469/how-can-i-change-ruby-to-version-1-9-3-again-with-rvm).

Hope it helps :)