# Restarting server on git push using hooks

Tags: git, bash, rvm

I'm trying to get my post-update git hook to stop the server, pull the changes from the updated repository, and start the server again. The hook is running, but it keeps spitting out errors.

Here are the errors:

```
remote: RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
remote: You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
...
remote: /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find thin (>= 0) amongst [] (Gem::LoadError)
...
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

Here's the post-update file:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH=/home/... (the value of "echo $PATH" on the remote server)
rvm use 1.9.3
cd /home/project_directory
thin stop
git pull ../gitdirectory.git
thin start -e production -p 3000 -d
```

Even replacing rvm and thin with their exact locations, i.e. "which rvm," didn't resolve the errors.

Can anyone shine some light on what's going wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `rvm` problem is well-known, irritating, and [answered elsewhere.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11283066/877115) Try the techniques listed on the [rvm site.](https://rvm.io/workflow/scripting/) As for the `git` error, it looks like you're simply issuing the command in the wrong directory. Have you tried running it on the server as the hook's user?

Answer (score 0):

For `rvm use ...` you need to `source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` but this would not work with the shell you used in shebang `#!/bin/sh`.

Instead try this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/project_directory
source $( $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm in . do rvm env --path )
thin stop
git pull ../gitdirectory.git
thin start -e production -p 3000 -d
```