# Please upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 or newer to continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I get this error when I navigate to my Rails application in production:

```
Rails 4 prefers to run on Ruby 2.0.

You're running
  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Please upgrade to Ruby 1.9.3 or newer to continue.
```

When I type `ruby -v` in the terminal, I get:

```
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-linux]
```

When type `rvm list` I get:

```
rvm rubies

 * ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.0.0-p481 [ x86_64 ]
```

Comment: How did you deploy to production?

Comment: Also what does `ruby -v` say on the production machine?

Comment: @kdeisz ruby -v says ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: @jsort i deployed using git deploy gem

Comment: No RVM/Rbenv should be deployed to production server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phusion Passenger author here. RVM commands like `rvm use` have absolutely no effect on your problem. That's because the Ruby interpreter that Phusion Passenger uses to run your app with, is not controlled from the shell using the `rvm` command, but only through the use of the [passenger_ruby](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRuby) configuration option.

Why is this the case? Because RVM (and rbenv, and chruby, and pretty much anything else out there) are implemented by setting environment variables in the shell. But as [explained in the Phusion Passenger manual](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#about_environment_variables), environment variables are not system-wide: they are inherited on a per-process basis. Thus, any environment variables you set in bash, only affect bash and its subprocesses, not Nginx. Because the latter is started by the init system.

The passenger_ruby configuration option is **the** option to control which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger gets to use to run your app with.

Comment: Apart from Passenger you will probably want to perform bundle install and rails console, so no RVM/Rbenv/passenger_ruby should be in place. Use /bin/alternatives and choose required version once and forever.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell RVM to temporarily use a particular Ruby using:

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```

That selected Ruby won't be remembered between launches of command-line sessions, because that doesn't tell RVM to use that version as a default. Add `--default` and it will:

```
rvm use 2.0.0 --default
```

From the built-in help:

```
To set a ruby as the user default, use the --default option.

    $ rvm use 1.9.3 --default

Please see documentation for further information:

  https://rvm.io/rvm/basics
```

When I run `rvm list`, there's some important information displayed that you seem to have overlooked:

```
rvm list

rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Notice the legend showing which is the current and the default Ruby. Compare that to yours.

Also, notice that you're seeing:

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

That'd be the version of Ruby installed in the system. Either the user you're running your Rails session as does *not* have RVM installed and initialized, or somehow RVM is being told to switch to the system Ruby.

Also, you might have a RVM directive in that directory, so read "[rvmrc files](http://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc)" and "[Typical RVM Project Workflow](http://rvm.io/workflow/projects)" to see if something there might be affecting you.

Comment: I tried many solutions but all did not solve the problem , it seems that passenger stuck on system ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: Use `which passenger` to find where it's hiding. It's probably only in the 1.8.7 directory.

Comment: this output of which passenger /home/ahmed/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/passenger

Answer (score 1):

This is my personal opinion: Avoid using RMV on production. There is a tool called **alternatives** available on CentOS and probably other linux distributions.

```
ruby_setup.sh
```

.

```
#/bin/sh
if [ "$RUBY_VERSION" == '2.0.0' ]; then
  yum -y install ruby20 rubygems20 ruby-devel
  alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.0
elif [ "$RUBY_VERSION" == '1.9.3' ]; then
  yum -y install ruby19 rubygems19 ruby19-devel
  alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9
elif [ "$RUBY_VERSION" == '1.8.7' ]; then
  yum -y install ruby18 rubygems18 ruby18-devel
  alternatives --set ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
else
  exit 1
fi

gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

.

```
RUBY_VERSION=2.0.0 ruby_setup.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0p481
```

If this doesn't work try this command as first:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM
```

See this similar question: "[How do I change my Ruby version using RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663936/how-do-i-change-my-ruby-version-using-rvm)", and this [documentation](http://rvm.io/rubies/default).

Comment: Try to use this command `rvm --default use 2.0.0`, as this [documentation](http://rvm.io/rubies/default)