# RVM ruby version 2.2.1, Actual ruby version 1.8.7

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rvm, virtual-machine

I am trying to install Jekyll in a VM for my web course and it required ruby >= 2.0.0.

I've gone through installing RVM and using this to install the desired version of ruby, but I then get the following:

```
vagrant@precise32:~/.rvm/bin$ bash rvm list

 rvm rubies

    ruby-2.1.1 [ i686 ]
 =* ruby-2.2.1 [ i686 ]

  # => - current
  # =* - current && default
  #  * - default

 vagrant@precise32:~/.rvm/bin$ ruby -v 
 ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30
 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux] 

 vagrant@precise32:~/.rvm/bin$ sudo gem
 install jekyll ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:jekyll requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0. 

 vagrant@precise32:~/.rvm/bin
```

I don't understand why it still thinks it is using version 1.8.7, as it confirms that it has installed 2.2.1.

I have done the following:

1. Use sudo chown to change ownership of the .gnupg folder recursively to vagrant (my system user) as defined [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1236084).
2. Install RVM following the instructions [here](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).
3. Installed the version (2.2.1) of ruby using these instructions (`https://rvm.io/rubies/installing`).
4. Tried to install Jekyll using sudo gem install jekyll, but I get an error saying that I need ruby version 2.0 or higher.

I'm not a developer, this is an introductory web development course. Also please excuse the corrupt link, I can't post more than 2.

Update: I think I might need to do something as described here: [How do I change my Ruby version using RVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663936/how-do-i-change-my-ruby-version-using-rvm).

Also - although I installed RVM, I originally installed it using sudo apt-get which corrupted it. I uninstalled that, and ran the most recent install with curl. To use it I have to navigate to the directory and use "bash rvm list"

Answer (score 0):

Add following two lines:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

to your `$HOME/.profile` file and restart a shell.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your machine is using Its own instead by RVM.

**1:** `rvm list` # Listing install rubies will you get versions of ruby which is installed by RVM

**2:**  `rvm use < ruby-version >` # for instances ruby-1.9.3-p125

**3:** `bundle install`

> **4:** Tried to install Jekyll using sudo gem install jekyll, but I get an
>   error saying that I need ruby version 2.0 or higher.

For that you could try [Installing Jekyll on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521806/installing-jekyll-on-ubuntu-14-04/34523631#34523631)

Hope this help you !!!