# `raw_require_paths': NotImplementedError (NotImplementedError)

Tags: ruby, path, yeoman, compass-sass, compass

None of my ruby commands work. 
Originally I was trying to get compass to work with Grunt within a yeoman generated project, but somehow I've messed up everything on my computer.

Its an older mac, which I can't upgrade the OS beyond 10.6.8. (snow leopard)

`Ruby -v`: `ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin10.0]`

If I type any `gem` command I get the following:

```
Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:219:in `raw_require_paths': NotImplementedError (NotImplementedError)
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb:240:in `require_paths'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:1098:in `register_default_spec'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:773:in `block in load_defaults'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:738:in `block in each_spec'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:723:in `block (2 levels) in each_gemspec'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:722:in `each'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:722:in `block in each_gemspec'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:721:in `each'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:721:in `each_gemspec'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:736:in `each_spec'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:770:in `load_defaults'
from /Users/home/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:1239:in `<top (required)>'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require'
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

My .bash_profile looks like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
alias ll="ls -lahG"
export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"
export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:"$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session. 
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" #Load RVM function
if [ -f ~/.git-completion.bash ]; then
source ~/.git-completion.bash
fi
eval "$(rbenv init -)"


##
# Your previous /Users/home/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/home/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2016-10-31_at_23:29:59
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2016-10-31_at_23:29:59: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by partially following these instructions from here [How to upgrade ruby and rails in mac os snow leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979900/how-to-upgrade-ruby-and-rails-in-mac-os-snow-leopard)

> RVM (Ruby Version Manager) is the Standard for upgrading your Ruby
>   installation on OSX: https://rvm.io (Any Platform - Including OSX Snow
>   Leopard)
>
> To get started, open a Terminal Window and issue the following
>   command:
>
> `\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

I then had a warning that I needed to use `rvm cleanup all` with `the --auto-dotfiles` flag

I then `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p194@global`to a previous install that worked.